# Defining a variable with or without export

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What is `export` for?

What is the difference between:

```
export name=value
```

and

```
name=value
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68529921/exporting-a-function-local-variable-to-the-environment

Answer (score 1348, accepted):

`export` makes the variable available to sub-processes.

That is,

```
export name=value
```

means that the variable name is available to *any process* you run from that shell process. If you want a process to make use of this variable, use `export`, and run the process from that shell.

```
name=value
```

means the variable scope is restricted to the shell, and is not available to any other process. You would use this for (say) loop variables, temporary variables etc.

It's important to note that exporting a variable doesn't make it available to parent processes. That is, specifying and exporting a variable in a spawned process doesn't make it available in the process that launched it.

Comment: Specifically export makes the variable available to child processes via the environment.

Comment: I'd also add that if the export is in a file that you "source" (like . filename) then it exports it to your working environment as well.

Comment: @rogerdpack can't you do that without export? cat > blah \n a=hi \n . blah; echo $a;   outputs 'hi' for me.

Comment: Nice it does work even without the export.  So I guess when sourcing a file, if you use export it will be reflected in child processes, if you don't it will just affect the local bash environment...

Comment: Thank you. Finally someone who also explains why you might not want to use export. That's the part I couldn't understand. I kept thinking the variable wouldn't be there as soon as you ran the next program in the script.

Comment: There's one edge-case to this; `name=value command` *does* make the variable available in the sub-process `command`.

Comment: It seems to work so that if the variable is already an exported variable, you can assign it without `export`, and the change is visible to a background process. (I tested with PATH variable in bash and dash scripts.)

Comment: Dissecting the meaning of "available": a snapshot is taken at the time a subprocess is started. Exporting a variable after that point does not percolate down to the already-running subprocesses.

Comment: @rogerdpack I tested that even if you do not write "export" and still source the file. The variable is available for use.

Comment: In case of `export` are values written to the variable in the sub shell also visible in the parent shell?

Answer (score 341):

To illustrate what the other answers are saying:

```
$ foo="Hello, World"
$ echo $foo
Hello, World
$ bar="Goodbye"
$ export foo
$ bash
bash-3.2$ echo $foo
Hello, World
bash-3.2$ echo $bar

bash-3.2$
```

Comment: One more example for this `al$ foobar="Whatever" bash`

Comment: Just in case someone wants to try this in Bash with arrays (like I did...) then a heads-up: [it can't be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564418/exporting-an-array-in-bash-script).

Answer (score 94):

It has been said that it's not necessary to export in bash when spawning subshells, while others said the exact opposite. It is important to note the difference between subshells (those that are created by `()`, ``` `` ```, `$()` or loops) and subprocesses (processes that are invoked by name, for example a literal `bash` appearing in your script).

- Sub*shells* **will** have access to all variables from the parent, regardless of their exported state.
- Sub*processes* will **only** see the exported variables.

What is common in these two constructs is that neither can pass variables back to the parent shell.

```
$ noexport=noexport; export export=export; (echo subshell: $noexport $export; subshell=subshell); bash -c 'echo subprocess: $noexport $export; subprocess=subprocess'; echo parent: $subshell $subprocess
subshell: noexport export
subprocess: export
parent:
```

There is one more source of confusion: some think that 'forked' subprocesses are the ones that don't see non-exported variables. Usually fork()s are immediately followed by exec()s, and that's why it would seem that the fork() is the thing to look for, while in fact it's the exec(). You can run commands without fork()ing first with the `exec` command, and processes started by this method will also have no access to unexported variables:

```
$ noexport=noexport; export export=export; exec bash -c 'echo execd process: $noexport $export; execd=execd'; echo parent: $execd
execd process: export
```

Note that we don't see the `parent:` line this time, because we have replaced the parent shell with the `exec` command, so there's nothing left to execute that command.

Comment: I've never seen a loop that (by itself) created a subshell; OTOH a pipeline does (always for pieces other than the last, sometimes for the last depending on your shell, version, and options). Backgrounding (`&`) also creates a subshell.

Comment: What about these `var=asdf bash -c 'echo $var'` or `var=asdf exec bash -c 'echo $var'`? The output is `asdf`. The `;` makes difference if placed after the variable definition. What would be the explanation? It looks like the `var` (with no `;`) regards to spawned subprocess somehow, due to origin shell has nothing to do with it. `echo $var` prints nothing if executed on second line. But one lined `var=asdf bash -c 'echo $var'; echo $var` gives `asdf\nasdf`.

Comment: @4xy That's a different case altogether; `var=value command` sets the variable `var` to the value `value` for the duration of the command `command`, in that command's environment. This is vaguely similar to what the `env` command does.

Answer (score 86):

This answer is *wrong* but retained for historical purposes.  See 2nd edit below.

Others have answered that export makes the variable available to subshells, and that is correct but merely a side effect.  When you export a variable, it puts that variable in the environment of the current shell (ie the shell calls `putenv(3)` or `setenv(3)`).
The environment of a process is inherited across exec, making the variable visible in subshells.

**Edit (with 5 years' perspective):**
This is a silly answer.  The purpose of 'export' is to make variables "be in the environment of subsequently executed commands", whether those commands be subshells or subprocesses.  A naive implementation would be to simply put the variable in the environment of the shell, but this would make it impossible to implement `export -p`.

**2nd Edit (with another 5 years in passing).**
This answer is just bizarre.  Perhaps I had some reason at one point to claim that bash puts the exported variable into its own environment, but those reasons were not given here and are now lost to history.  See [Exporting a function local variable to the environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68529921/exporting-a-function-local-variable-to-the-environment).

Comment: Note that this is not entirely true.  In `bash`, export does indeed add the variable to the environment of the current shell, but this is not the case with `dash`.  It seems to me that adding the variable to the environment of the current shell is the simplest way to implement the semantics of `export`, but that behavior is not mandated.

Comment: I'm not sure what `dash` has to do with this. The original poster was asking specifically about `bash`.

Comment: The question is tagged `bash` but applies equally to any bourne-shell variant.  Being overly specific and providing answers that apply only to `bash` is a great evil.

Comment: `bash` is the jQuery of the shell.

Comment: `export makes the variable available to subshells, and that is correct` This is a very confusing use of terminology. Subshells don't need `export` to inherit variables. Subprocesses do.

Comment: "When you export a variable, it puts that variable in the environment of the current shell" This is not correct, see 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68529921/exporting-a-function-local-variable-to-the-environment

Answer (score 39):

`export NAME=value` for settings and variables that have meaning to a subprocess.

`NAME=value` for temporary or loop variables private to the current shell process.

In more detail, `export` marks the variable name in the environment that copies to a subprocesses and their subprocesses upon creation.  No name or value is ever copied back from the subprocess.

- A common error is to place a space around the equal sign:

  ```
  $ export FOO = "bar"  
  bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
  ```
- Only the exported variable (`B`) is seen by the subprocess:

  ```
  $ A="Alice"; export B="Bob"; echo "echo A is \$A. B is \$B" | bash
  A is . B is Bob
  ```
- Changes in the subprocess do not change the main shell:

  ```
  $ export B="Bob"; echo 'B="Banana"' | bash; echo $B
  Bob
  ```
- Variables marked for export have values copied when the subprocess is created:

  ```
  $ export B="Bob"; echo '(sleep 30; echo "Subprocess 1 has B=$B")' | bash &
  [1] 3306
  $ B="Banana"; echo '(sleep 30; echo "Subprocess 2 has B=$B")' | bash 
  Subprocess 1 has B=Bob
  Subprocess 2 has B=Banana
  [1]+  Done         echo '(sleep 30; echo "Subprocess 1 has B=$B")' | bash
  ```
- Only exported variables become part of the environment (`man environ`):

  ```
   $ ALICE="Alice"; export BOB="Bob"; env | grep "ALICE\|BOB"
   BOB=Bob
  ```

So, now it should be as clear as is the summer's sun!   Thanks to Brain Agnew, alexp, and William Prusell.

Answer (score 22):

It should be noted that you can export a variable and later change the value. The variable's changed value will be available to child processes.  Once export has been set for a variable you must do `export -n <var>` to remove the property.

```
$ K=1
$ export K
$ K=2
$ bash -c 'echo ${K-unset}'
2
$ export -n K
$ bash -c 'echo ${K-unset}'
unset
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the information I was looking for because I saw a script which used environment variables and then "re-exported" them w/ a new value, and I was wondering if it was necessary.

Answer (score 18):

`export` will make the variable available to all shells forked from the current shell.

Comment: Hi John, do you know whether the position of this export matters?  Should I put it at the bottom of the makefile or anywhere is okay?

Comment: @leolehu `export` in a `Makefile` is generally a separate question. [Quick experimentation](https://ideone.com/X8f0gY) reveals that, predictably, the location of the `export` is unimportant. (Predictable because `make` will parse and process the entire `Makefile` and _then_ attempt to resolve dependencies to figure out which target(s) to run.)

Answer (score 16):

As you might already know, UNIX allows processes to have a set of environment variables, which are key/value pairs, both key and value being strings.
Operating system is responsible for keeping these pairs for each process separately.

Program can access its environment variables through this UNIX API:

- `char *getenv(const char *name);`
- `int setenv(const char *name, const char *value, int override);`
- `int unsetenv(const char *name);`

Processes also inherit environment variables from parent processes. Operating system is responsible for creating a copy of all "envars" at the moment the child process is created.

*Bash*, among other shells, is capable of setting its environment variables on user request. This is what `export` exists for.

`export` is a Bash command to set environment variable for Bash. All variables set with this command would be inherited by all processes that this Bash would create.

More on [Environment in Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Environment.html#Environment)

Another kind of variable in Bash is internal variable. Since Bash is not just interactive shell, it is in fact a script interpreter, as any other interpreter (e.g. Python) it is capable of keeping its own set of variables. It should be mentioned that Bash (unlike Python) supports only string variables.

Notation for defining Bash variables is `name=value`. These variables stay inside Bash and have nothing to do with environment variables kept by operating system.

More on [Shell Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html#Shell-Parameters) (including variables)

Also worth noting that, according to Bash reference manual:

> The environment for any simple command or function may be augmented
>   temporarily by prefixing it with parameter assignments, as described
>   in [Shell Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html#Shell-Parameters). These assignment statements affect only the
>   environment seen by that command.

---

To sum things up:

- `export` is used to set environment variable in operating system. This variable will be available to all child processes created by current Bash process ever after.
- Bash variable notation (name=value) is used to set local variables available only to current process of bash
- Bash variable notation prefixing another command creates environment variable only for scope of that command.

Comment: bash vars don't support as many types as Python, but do have string, integer, and two kinds of array ('indexed'/traditional and 'associative' which is similar to awk array, perl hash, or Python dict). Other shells vary; only string is _portable_.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - Actually, all are stored as string arrays and automatically converted if necessary for arithmetic, etc. A common variable like `A="string"` is actually identical to `A[0]="string"`. In fact, after saying `A="string"`, you could concatenate more strings to the 1-string array with  `A[1]="string2"`, `A+=(string3 string4 "string 5 is longer")` then `echo "${A[@]}"` to print them. Note that it would require something like feeding the array to a `printf` command in order to get some kind of delimiter between strings since the default is a space and string5 contains spaces.

Comment: @DocSalvager: `export a b; a=this; b[0]=that; env | grep ^[ab]` isn't identical. In C/C++/Java `float` and `double` are interchangeable in _some_ situations but they are still different types.

Answer (score 9):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1158231/7154924) implies this, but I'd like to make explicit the connection to shell builtins:

As mentioned already, `export` will make a variable available to both the shell and children. If `export` is *not* used, the variable will only be available in the shell, and only shell *builtins* can access it.

That is,

```
tango=3
env | grep tango # prints nothing, since env is a child process
set | grep tango # prints tango=3 - "type set" shows `set` is a shell builtin
```

Answer (score 7):

Two of the creators of UNIX, Brian Kernighan and Rob Pike, explain this in their book "The UNIX Programming Environment". Google for the title and you'll easily find a pdf version.

They address shell variables in section 3.6, and focus on the use of the `export` command at the end of that section:

> When you want to make the value of a variable accessible in sub-shells, the shell's export command should be used. (You might think about why there is no way to export the value of a variable from a sub-shell to its parent).

Answer (score 4):

Here's yet another example:

```
VARTEST="value of VARTEST" 
#export VARTEST="value of VARTEST" 
sudo env | grep -i vartest 
sudo echo ${SUDO_USER} ${SUDO_UID}:${SUDO_GID} "${VARTEST}" 
sudo bash -c 'echo ${SUDO_USER} ${SUDO_UID}:${SUDO_GID} "${VARTEST}"'
```

Only by using export VARTEST the value of VARTEST is available in sudo bash -c '...'!

For further examples see:

- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell
- bash-hackers.org/wiki/doku.php/scripting/processtree

Answer (score 3):

Just to show the difference between an exported variable being in the environment (env) and a non-exported variable not being in the environment:

If I do this:

```
$ MYNAME=Fred
$ export OURNAME=Jim
```

then only $OURNAME appears in the env. The variable $MYNAME is not in the env.

```
$ env | grep NAME
OURNAME=Jim
```

but the variable $MYNAME does exist in the shell

```
$ echo $MYNAME
Fred
```

Comment: Hi Will, can I export a variable before the variable declaration? like export OURNAME and then OURNAME=Jim?

Comment: @leoleohu if you export OURNAME before you assign it, you'll just export an empty string.

Comment: @ingernet even if you export variable before assigning it, any value assigned to that variable until before the child process is invoked will be seen by the child process. But once the child process is invoked, any updates to the exported variable done in the parent process will not be seen by the child process, that's because the variables are copied by value during process 'exec' call

Answer (score 3):

By default, variables created within a script are only available to the current shell; child processes (sub-shells) will not have access to values that have been set or modified. Allowing child processes to see the values, requires use of the export command.

Answer (score 1):

As yet another corollary to the existing answers here, let's rephrase the problem statement.

The answer to "should I `export`" is identical to the answer to the question "Does your subsequent code run a command which *implicitly* accesses this variable?"

For a properly documented standard utility, the answer to this can be found in the ENVIRONMENT section of the utility's man page. So, for example, the [`git` manual page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/git.1.html#ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES) mentions that `GIT_PAGER` controls which utility is used to browse multi-page output from `git`. Hence,

```
# XXX FIXME: buggy
branch="main"
GIT_PAGER="less"
git log -n 25 --oneline "$branch"
git log "$branch"
```

will not work correctly, because you did not `export GIT_PAGER`. (Of course, if your system already declared the variable as exported somewhere else, the bug is not reproducible.)

We are *explicitly* referring to the variable `$branch`, and the `git` program code doesn't refer to a system variable `branch` anywhere (as also suggested by the fact that its name is written in lower case; but many beginners erroneously use upper case for their private variables, too! See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) for a discussion) so there is no reason to `export branch`.

The correct code would look like

```
branch="main"
export GIT_PAGER="less"
git log -n 25 --oneline "$branch"
git log -p "$branch"
```

(or equivalently, you can explicitly prefix each invocation of `git` with the temporary assignment

```
branch="main"
GIT_PAGER="less" git log -n 25 --oneline "$branch"
GIT_PAGER="less" git log -p "$branch"
```

In case it's not obvious, the shell script syntax

```
var=value command arguments
```

temporarily sets `var` to `value` for the duration of the execution of

```
command arguments
```

and exports it to the `command` subprocess, and then afterwards, reverts it back to the previous value, which could be undefined, or defined with a different - possibly empty - value, and unexported if that's what it was before.)

For internal, ad-hoc or otherwise poorly documented tools, you simply have to know whether they silently inspect their environment. This is rarely important in practice, outside of a few specific use cases, such as passing a password or authentication token or other secret information to a process running in some sort of container or isolated environment.

If you really need to know, and have access to the source code, look for code which uses the `getenv` system call (or on Windows, with my condolences, variations like `getenv_s`, `w_getenv`, etc). For some scripting languages (such as Perl or Ruby), look for `ENV`. For Python, look for `os.environ` (but notice also that e.g. `from os import environ as foo` means that `foo` is now an alias for `os.environ`). In Node, look for `process.env`. For C and related languages, look for `envp` (but this is just a convention for what to call the optional third argument to `main`, after `argc` and `argv`; the language lets you call them anything you like). For shell scripts (as briefly mentioned above), perhaps look for variables with uppercase or occasionally mixed-case names, or usage of the utility `env`. Many informal scripts have undocumented but discoverable assignments usually near the beginning of the script; in particular, look for the `?=` default assignment [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

For a brief demo, here is a shell script which invokes a Python script which looks for `$NICKNAME`, and falls back to a default value if it's unset.

```
#!/bin/sh
NICKNAME="Handsome Guy"
demo () {
    python3 <<\____
from os import environ as env
print("Hello, %s" % env.get("NICKNAME", "Anonymous Coward"))
____
}
demo
# prints "Hello, Anonymous Coward"
# Fix: forgot export
export NICKNAME
demo
# prints "Hello, Handsome Guy"
```

As another tangential remark, let me reiterate that you only ever need to `export` a variable once. Many beginners cargo-cult code like

```
# XXX FIXME: redundant exports
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/acme/bin:$PATH"
```

but typically, your operating system has already declared `PATH` as exported, so this is better written

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
PATH="/opt/acme/bin:$PATH"
```

or perhaps refactored to something like

```
for p in "$HOME/bin" "/opt/acme/bin"
do
    case :$PATH: in
     *:"$p":*) ;;
     *) PATH="$p:$PATH";;
    esac
done
# Avoid polluting the variable namespace of your interactive shell
unset p
```

which avoids adding duplicate entries to your `PATH`.

Comment: "typically, your operating system has already declared PATH as exported" -- I believe whatever environment variables that are set in the environment of `bash` when `bash` started will automatically be exported?

Comment: Yeah, but there are many other shells out there too.

Answer (score 0):

Although not explicitly mentioned in the discussion, it is NOT necessary to use export when spawning a subshell from inside bash since all the variables are copied into the child process.

Comment: Please explain as what you are saying seems to directly contradict the answers w/ examples above.

Comment: This is the right way if you don't want the variables to be exported globally but only available to the subprocess! Thank you.

Comment: @MikeLippert What Scott means by subshell is the ones created by process substitution $() or ``, subshells created by commands in parentheses (command1; command2) etc automatically inherit all parent shell's variables even if they're not exported. But child processes or scripts invoked won't see all shell variables unless they're exported. This is one of the major differences and is often misunderstood

Comment: @Pavan Ah, now that is very helpful. Because a subshell created by invoking a new bash process is NOT what he meant and would only receive exported variables. And that is what I was thinking of when I asked that question so many years ago.