# Linux/Unix environment variables

Tags: linux, unix, environment-variables

Where Linux/Unix environment variables are kept? How can I add my own environment variable and make it persistent, not only within currently running script?

Comment: http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-environment-variables.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add them in your profile, eg `~/.bash_profile`. global profile is usually located in /etc. eg `/etc/profile`. Take a look also at `/etc/profile.d` directory if you have it.

Comment: I don't see /etc/profile, but I see /etc/profile.d which contains gvfs-bash-completion.sh and speechd-user-port.sh files. What exactly should I do to add environment variables for all users?

Comment: those in `/etc/profile.d` are custom profiles. For all users, if you don't have `/etc/profile` then create it.

Answer (score 1):

To see the env variables use the `printenv` command.

To set a new variable you can use the  `~/.bash_rc`  file:

```
export new_variable=10
```

`new_variable` will be accessible for all shells.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean ~/.bashrc file? 
What about setting environment variable for all users?

Comment: No spaces around `=`. `export new_variable=10` or it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the `export` keyword?

More information:

- [Defining a variable with or without export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/bash-defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export)
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash.html - section Environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

Add `export` statements to `~/.bash_login`

Comment: I don't see ~/.bash_login file. Can I create it? What is the difference between ~/.bash_login and ~/.bashrc?

Comment: @alex You can create one. bash_login runs for login shells and bashrc for interactive shells - check the man page for details.