# Rigid set JAVA_HOME variable in Linux

Tags: java, linux, unix, hadoop, environment-variables

I'm trying to run all hadoop daemons with the command

```
./start-all.sh
```

from the main host cluster. As a result of execution several times gave out

```
starting namenode, logging to /export/hadoop-1.0.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop--namenode-one.out
192.168.1.10: starting datanode, logging to /export/hadoop-1.0.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-myhost2.out
192.168.1.10: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.
```

And it happened several times even after execution on the virtual machine to the address of 192.168.1.10 commands

```
hadoop@myhost2:~$ export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_06
```

Tell please how rigidly once and for all to fix the JAVA_HOME variable.

Comment: Probably related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460633/linux-unix-environment-variables

Answer (score 1):

Put the line `export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java` at the beginning of your start-all.sh script, and that should do it.

Comment: but this will only do the job only for this script not globally

Comment: It should apply to all daemons launched from the script.

Comment: yes but for daemons launched from that script only not for other scripts.

Comment: True, but since the problem is only dealing with those daemons launched from this script, it seemed better to localize it.

Comment: hadoop-env.sh file comes in picture..

Answer (score 1):

`$ vi ~/.bash_proflle`

append this line to the file

`export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_06`

that will make permanent changes to `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud set **JAVA_HOME** in `hadoop-env.sh` file also. Which is in `$HADOOP_INSTALL/hadoop/conf` directory of hadoop. by default JAVA_HOME setting line is commented

> **hadoop-env.sh** - This file contains some environment variable settings
>   used by Hadoop. You can use these to affect some aspects of Hadoop
>   daemon behavior, such as where log files are stored, the maximum
>   amount of heap used etc. The only variable you should need to change
>   in this file is JAVA_HOME

Or You can add it in following file in hadoop account.

```
~/.bash_proflle
```