# Export path in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

What is the difference between:

```
PATH=$PATH:/Projects/persevere/bin
```

and

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Projects/persevere/bin
```

I think both are working.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/bash-defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line does not export the variable (to the environment variables) unless it is already there.

Bash keeps internal variables accessible only by itself, that is, commands you run don't see them.

For example:

```
internal_var=hello
export external_var=there
env
```

The `env` (which lists environment variables) command won't list internal_var but will list external_var

Comment: Actually, in the specific case of PATH, it's already marked for export so there's no difference at all.