# How to call a bash script from another script?

Tags: bash, shell, call

I have two very simple scripts. I have asked this question but people thought I am doing it in different platform. Actually these two scripts are in same folder.

One is **source.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "start"
./call.sh
echo "end"
```

And second is call.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
passDir="/etc/passwd"
while read line
do
    while true
        do
            echo "prompt"
            #propmt for username
            read -p "Enter username : " username
            egrep "^$username" $passDir >/dev/null
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "$username exists!"
            else
                userName=$username
                break
            fi
        done                    
done < user.txt
```

and **user.text** file is only two words in two lines

```
Hello
world
```

**Output:**

```
exisats!
prompt
exisats!
prompt
exisats!
prompt
exisats!
prompt
exisats!
prompt
exisats!
prompt
```

Until I press Ctrl+d I really appreciate if anyone can tel how I can fix this.

Comment: [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352851/how-to-call-shell-script-from-another-shell-script)

Comment: @DOOM I saw that before. I can call another script and it is fine but when it comes to prompting information in the called script it goes to loop!

Comment: Have you redirected standard input anywhere? Are you running this from cron or some other automated system?

Comment: @EtanReisner I am running this from my laptop in same environment same folder.

Comment: How are you running the main script when this fails to work? Are there other `read` statements in that script (or the other scripts) that work correctly when you run the main script?

Comment: Can you give us a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: @EtanReisner I have uploaded all the code. I call main script from terminal on ubuntu. Please have a look at the added code.

Comment: @Beta I have edited my question completely. Hope it makes much sense to you.

Comment: You would have this exact same problem if you didn't have `source.sh` at all and only invoked `call.sh` directly. Thus, the way you ask this question (as if it's an issue about scripts calling each other) is misleading.

Comment: `dos2unix user.text`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce this to a **minimal example**:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    echo line is $line

    echo "prompt"
    read -p "Enter username : " username

    echo username is $username

done < user.txt
```

Now the problem is clear: the script reads *everything* from `user.txt`.

Only `read` should read from `user.txt`. We can tell `read` to do this by means of a **file descriptor**:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3< user.txt    # open the file, give it File Descriptor 3

while read -r -u3 line
do
    echo line is $line

    echo "prompt"
    read -p "Enter username : " username

    echo username is $username

done

exec 3<&-    # close the file
```

Comment: Why read-write? I'd think that read-only access would be more appropriate here. Also, scoping the FD to the while loop would prevent it from leaking into future parts of the script.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I'm sure you're right. I'm not a bash expert, I just posted the first solution I got to work. May I take those tricks from your solution, to improve mine?

Comment: Absolutely; please do. (To explain the use of `read -r`, by the way -- by default, `read` processes backslash-escape sequences; to get the behavior which would otherwise be a more reasonable default, of representing data exactly as read, the `-r` flag is necessary).