# How to run a shell script within another shell script

Tags: shell

I have a shell script like

```
a="2 3 6"
b="winter summer"
c="model1 model2"

for i in $a;do
 cd "directory_$i"
 sh script.sh
 cd -
done
```

Where script.sh is

```
 for j in $b;do
   for k in $c;do
     some computation
   done
 done
```

When I am running this, it is not executing the script.sh.

Comment: Try $(/bin/bash script.sh)

Comment: Please explain what you want to obtain in more detail... Your code doen not make much sense, as-is...

Comment: in `script.sh` you are using variables that are set in the first script, so `script.sh` does not know its values. You probably have to pass those as arguments.

Comment: When you want the results of script.sh in your first script (variables set), you need to `source script.sh`.

Comment: please refer to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352851/how-to-call-shell-script-from-another-shell-script