# Unable to execute a script from another shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script (`A`) which begins with a `#!/bin/sh` shebang.

There is another file (`B`) which doesn't begin with `#!/bin/sh`; it has some environment variables which I need to set for `A` to work.

The file `B` runs fine, and sets the variables when executed from `.bash_profile`.  For example, in my `.bash_profile` file:

```
{. /(full_path)/(envname)/(filename).sh;}
```

When I write same line in my `A` script file, nothing happens.  Why not?

I did `echo $env_variable_name`; this gives me the correct path when executed via `.bash_profile` but gives me blank when via my script `A`. I tried

- ```
  /(full_path)/(envname)/(filename).sh
  ```
- ```
  SCRIPT_FULL_NAME=$(readlink -f "$0")
  SCRIPT_PATH=$(dirname $SCRIPT_FULL_NAME)
  sh ${SCRIPT_PATH}/(filename).sh
  ```

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidelines on how to write questions. For starters:
1. Please format your code.
2. Add more code to your question to help us understand it better and for future readers to benefit from this question.
3. Look for other questions which might help you out already. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352851/how-to-call-shell-script-from-another-shell-script
4. Format your text, and give us a minimum working example.

Comment: What's in your `B` file?  Make sure it has no bashisms (e.g. `export foo=bar` rather than `foo=bar; export foo`) - or change `A`'s interpreter to `/bin/bash`.  You should be able to trace execution using `sh -x A`; that's often helpful in debugging shell scripts.

Answer (score 2):

> There is another file (B) which doesn't begin with #!/bin/sh; it has some environment variables which I need to set for A to work.

In this case you should *source* you script B in script A. To source a script in sh, the command is:

```
. /path/to/B.sh
```

Note that the `.` is not the beginning of a relative path to script B.

Comment: Also using the keyword `source` (which `.` is an alias for) might be more readable.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. Thanks. :)