# How trigger multiple dependent programs using shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I have an application which is modularised like this:

```
`APP
    PART1
       part1.sh
    PART2
       part2.o
    PART3
       part3.o`
```

Input file for part1.o generates a output file that is again input file for part2.o, which generates another file, which is input for part3.o and finally the output for overall app.

I'm intending to have a run.sh file that should take the first input file for the sub-application (part1) and so and forth trigger the rest of the sub-applications and store the last output in a file name, mentioned with command. Something like this:

```
run.sh input.txt output.txt
```

Currently my shell looks like this:

```
OUTPUT1="output1.txt"
OUTPUT2="output2.txt"
./PART1/part1.sh  $0 > OUTPUT1 &&
./PART2/part2.o < OUTPUT1 > OUTPUT2 &&
./PART3/part3.o < OUTPUT2 > $1
```

Currently, if I run this code, I get the following output indefinitely long:

```
+ ./run.sh
+ ./run.sh
+ ./run.sh
.
.
.
.
```

Can anyone help me with this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What were you expecting `< $0` to accomplish?  Do you really want `part1.sh` to process the contents of the file `run.sh`?

Comment: @John1024 I see.  I have fixed that part, but it still causes the same behavior. I want to trigger `part1.sh` from `run.sh` (the other way round).

Comment: What do you expect `./PART1/part1.sh  $0` to accomplish?  Please explain what you think `$0` means.

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/8352939/524743

Comment: @John1024 I thought i was referring to `input.txt` with `$0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using positional parameters incorrectly.

`run.sh input.txt output.txt`

will populate positional params with values given below

`$0` = `run.sh`

`$1` = `input.txt`

`$2` = `output.txt`

[More on positional params](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams)

Comment: Sweet. Got it. That was super dumb from my part. Thanks.