# How to manage a bunch of python programs

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, file-io, server

I have a lot of python programs that run on an old Ubuntu laptop to sync inventory feeds, track sales, and similar stuff where I work. If I ever have to restart the computer for one reason or another I have to open a bunch of shells and restart each program individually.

I was wondering if there is a good way to manage all these programs? I prefer them to each run in there own terminal as they print updates about what they are doing and errors that they may encounter (the errors are emailed to me as well).

I'm not really a "professional" programmer. I got hired on to do things like this by hand and just happened to know enough python to automate it. If I need to learn how to use some kind of server or should learn another language I'm fine with that I just need pointed in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: can try with crontasks or write services if its relatively new version 14+ of ubutu

Comment: Do they keep running forever, or do they run ?for a few mins, hours? and then terminate?

Comment: fast and easy - make one shell which runs on start -[link1- run a shell script on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup)- that runs commands to start all these programs up - [link2 - call a shell script from another shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352851/how-to-call-shell-script-from-another-shell-script)

Comment: @Drako I'll have to take a look at that, thanks.

Comment: @TomDalton They run forever although many of them I could have just run once a day.

Answer (score 0):

Installing packages into a virtual environment - In an activated virtual environment, you'll have a command `pip` that you'll use to install, update, and remove packages. Of course, pip has all sorts of options and other features, which you can read about in the [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/) but overall its great for efficient code management

Comment: I read the question to mean he has written the scripts himself, rather than them being existing pip packages. Even if they were existing pip-based programs, pip doesnt help orchestrate running them all...