# Running executable file with additional options or arguments

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script `Test.sh` that aims to execute `anotherscript` (a linux executable file):

```
#!/bin/bash -l
mp1='/my/path1/'
mp2='/my/path2/anotherscript'

for myfile in $mp1*.txt; do
    echo "$myfile" 

    "$mp2 $myfile -m mymode"
    echo "finished file"
done
```

Notice that `anotherscript` takes as arguments `$myfile` and options `-m mymode`.

But I get the file not found error (says `Test.sh: line 8: /my.path2/anotherscript: No such file or directory`).

My questions are:

1. I have [followed this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352851/how-to-call-shell-script-from-another-shell-script) to get my bash script to run the executable file. But I'm afraid I still get the error above.
2. Am I specifying arguments as they should to execute the file?

Comment: Try `"$mp2" "$myfile" -m mymode`.  Note that quoting values groups them together, e.g. `echo "hello"` != `"echo hello"`.

Comment: Maybe `sh -c "$mp2 $myfile -m mymode"` works

Comment: Where are the scripts located in your filesystem? Where from the file system are you running them? Did you remember to chmod +x both scripts?

Comment: @Perplexabot I did `chmod +x anotherscript` before attempting to run it through the bash script. Both scripts are somewhere in the file system. I have not add their directory to the `$PATH`.

Comment: @TomAtix and @0x5453, both suggestions work, thanks a lot. Feel free to add it as answers and I'll gladly accept them.
I'd like to know however why it isn't important to have `-m mymode` within quotations. Thanks once again!

Comment: Let us assume that both scripts are located in the same directory. That directory must be in $PATH if the directory isn't already in your $PATH. For example, as you may know, /usr/bin/, /bin/ are already in your $PATH. So shoving the scripts in those dirs should work. If you don't want to add that dir to your path, you can just cd into where they are and run the script.

Comment: @Perplexabot thanks, I understand. However, the idea was that I could indicate the file path without adding it to $PATH. I know this wasn't clear in my original post, so if you'd like to contribute an answer it is very appreciated!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use

```
sh -c "$mp2 $myfile -m mymode"
```

instead of just

```
"$mp2 $myfile -m mymode"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash -l

dir=`find /my/path1/ -name "*.txt"`
mp2='/my/path2/anotherscript'

for myfile in "$dir"; do
    echo "$myfile" 

    "$mp2" "$myfile" -m mymode
    echo "finished file"
done
```

Make sure `anotherscript` has execution right (`chmod +x anotherscript`).