# Calling another shell script based on getopts args passed

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I want to create a shell script that is should call one of two shell scripts based on the parameters passed.

For Example,

```
If -i & -s is exist in parameters list it should call script_1.sh
If -j is exist in parameters list it should call script_2.sh
```

script_call.sh should be like below,

```
while getopts :i:s:j OPTIONS
do
   case ${OPTIONS} in
      i)  INI_FILE=${OPTARG};;
      s)  INI_SECTION=${OPTARG};;
      #both -i & -s parameters passed, so call script_1.sh
      #script_1.sh -i ini_file.txt -s ini_section
      j)  JOB_KEY=${OPTARG};;
      #only -j parameter is passed, so call script_2.sh
      #script_2.sh -j 123
   esac
done
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call one shell script from another shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352851/how-to-call-one-shell-script-from-another-shell-script)

Comment: Thanks! JonnieJs. That question is about calling another plain shell script from current script but my question is calling shell script based on the parameters passed.

Comment: Don't add the call to run the script while parsing the args, but after the args processing. Because you need to handle cases when the order of flags is reversed, i.e. `-s` first and `-i` after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `:i:s:j` to `i:s:j:`, and use another `case` after the loop.

```
case ${INI_FILE+x},${INI_SECTION+x},${JOB_KEY+x} in
( x,x, ) script_1.sh -i "$INI_FILE" -s "$INI_SECTION" ;;
( ,,x  ) script_2.sh -j "$JOB_KEY" ;;
( *    ) : handle ambiguous parameters here
esac
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But the parameters (INI_FILE ,INI_SECTION,JOB_KEY) are not getting passed for script_1.sh & script_2.sh inside case statements.

Comment: @bala What do you mean *not getting passed*?

Comment: whatever parameters I got via getopts method, I'm unable to pass those parameters inside case statements as args for script_1.sh & script_2.sh

Comment: @ismail Thank You! It's working now after placing the semi-colon after j