# Running acme cron job into .sh file due to 'characters not allowed' for cron job command

Tags: bash, cron, acme.sh

My hosting provider panel doesn't allow to add next cron job command:

```
"/home/username/.acme.sh"/acme.sh --cron --home "/home/username/.acme.sh" > /dev/null
```

due to '*Some characters are not allowed for cron job command*' error.

After reading [this post](https://wp-ask.com/question/how-to-setup-cron-job-when-special-characters-not-allowed-by-my-hosting/) about it I'm trying to understand how to run it from a script (`~/run-acme.sh`) and add it to a cron job but don't know how to do it (the example is using a PHP script).

Here's the content of the `run-acme.sh` script but don't know what to write before the command (`source`, `.` or `bash`) as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58678218/496176) suggests:

**Option 1**:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
bash "/home/username/.acme.sh"/acme.sh --cron --home "/home/username/.acme.sh" > /dev/null
```

**Option 2**:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
source "/home/username/.acme.sh"/acme.sh --cron --home "/home/username/.acme.sh" > /dev/null
```

**Option 3**:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
. "/home/username/.acme.sh"/acme.sh --cron --home "/home/username/.acme.sh" > /dev/null
```

Which of these options will work? Do they run with the same result?

***Important note**: don't have access to crontab/SSH*

Comment: Please forgive if the title is not really clear but I don't know how to entitle it (could be a long one)

Comment: If you are trying to run a shell/bash from within another shell/bash -- simply use `sh /var/www/yourfile.sh` or `bash /var/www/yourfile.sh` --  It will fork the commend inside your script into child processes.  Simple enough if I understand your question correctly ..

Comment: What's gong to throw people off .. Is that `--cron --home` are not "standard" flags, so what you are trying to accomplish might need some more explanation / clarification.

Comment: @Zak don't know a thing about cron but `--cron --home` are parameters from the `acme.sh` [script](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh#2-or-install-from-git)

Comment: Looks like the redirection `>` isn't allowed. So put that line in a script and simply call that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want option 1, because you want to run the `acme.sh` script.

Option 2 and option 3 are essentially equivalent in bash, because `source` is an alias to `.` in bash. However, they are **not equivalent** in `sh`, because `.` exists in `sh` but `source` does not (this is because `source` a non-POSIX bash extension).

When `source` or `.` are used, this is similar to using `:load` in Haskell's GHCi or Scala's REPL, or `load` in Lisp or Clojure. The `source` or `.` commands tell the shell to read, parse, and evaluate code written in a separate source file *in the context of the current shell*. Essentially, it allows functions and variables defined in a separate file to be made available in the context of the "calling" shell script.

What option 1 will do is run the `acme.sh`. You want this option because you don't want the `acme.sh` script to be run in your current shell (you might have some aliases or functions already defined in your current shell that could cause naming collisions). Running `bash acme.sh` is similar to running `python my_code.py`: the bash interpreter will execute the contents of `acme.sh`.

For more info on `source` and `.`, see:

- `help source` and `help .` at your bash prompt
- [This superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/176788/1259970)
- [This askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/182020/1081385) (though sadly this answer does not explain that `source` is non-POSIX)