# How to use the arguments from `xargs` as the index of an array

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xargs, gnu-parallel

I want to use the aruments from the `xargs` as the index of this array, this is the scripts:

```
1 #!/bin/bash
2 array[0]=x
3 array[1]=y
4 echo array : ${array[0]}, ${array[1]}
5 echo -n {0..1} | xargs -I index -d" " echo index,${array[index]}
```

and this is the output:

```
[usr@linux scripts]$ sh test.sh 
array : x, y
0,x
1,x
```

you can see that the array can not accept the index correctly, it's always the first. How can I get this kind of output:

```
array : x, y
0,x
1,y
```

I showed the example with the command `echo`, however, my real aim is for another command, like this :

```
echo -n {0..1} | xargs -I index -d" " somecommand ${array[index]}
```

so that I want a general solution of this question.
And I also tried the `parallel` instead of the `xargs`, it's have the same problem.

Comment: This can't possibly work the way you want, because the array only exists in the shell and `xargs` works by creating child processes. The `${...}` stuff in the xargs command line is expanded only once, before xargs is executed. You'll have to either make the array available to child processes, or rewrite the xargs as a shell loop.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley OK, however, I want to use the `xargs` to do parallel, so a shell loop could not be a proper solution :(

Comment: You could try to put the array as a list in the environment and use that in the command started with `xargs`, but there could be corner cases...

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in `seq 0 $[${#array[@]}-1]`;do echo $i,${array[$i]};done|xargs -n1 echo
```

Comment: yes, it's a away to avoid this kind of problem. However, your scripts should be corrected a little: `for i in \`seq 0 \`expr ${#array[@]}-1\`\``

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

. `which env_parallel.bash`

array[0]=x
array[1]=y
echo array : ${array[0]}, ${array[1]}
echo -n {0..1} | env_parallel -d" " echo '{},${array[{}]}'
# or
echo -n {0..1} | env_parallel --env array -d" " echo '{},${array[{}]}'
```

Your problem boils to exporting arrays, which you cannot do without cheating:  [Exporting an array in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564418/exporting-an-array-in-bash-script)