# bash: pass multiple parameters from a single variable

Tags: bash

In a bash call I want to put some constant parameters to a variable and don't lose StdOut & StdErr inside a pipe.

I have a call

```
git fetch origin "ref1:ref1" "ref2:ref2" "ref3:ref3"
```

Let's I'll put those constant values to a variable

```
fetch_refspec="'ref1:ref1' 'ref2:ref2' 'ref3:ref3'"
```

I see a solution to use a pipe, but I'm afraid to lose the output somehow. And I do not want to use files for a caching (`tee` command).

```
echo $refs | xargs git origin
```

I don't understand how to do this stuff cleverly. Or if it possible at all.
Later I want to put the output to a variable and analyze it.

Comment: Use array as `fetch_refspec="(ref1:ref1' 'ref2:ref2' 'ref3:ref3'); git fetch origin "${fetch_refspec[@]}"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use a variable, use an array!

```
declare -a gitArgs=("ref1:ref1" "ref2:ref2" "ref3:ref3")
```

and pass it to the command you need,

```
git origin "${gitArgs[@]}"
```

Comment: Got harsh bugs :) with [Array variables may not (yet) be exported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564418/exporting-an-array-in-bash-script/5564589#5564589). But OK with it. Forced to use `source` command.

Comment: On the other hand, using of the `source` command to call subscripts kills preconditions. I.e. the shortest form `if [[ ... ]]; then exit` at beginning of subscripts now must be converted and wraped over entire script. And I have many preconditions ))