# Multiple (with one fixed) GNU-parallel arguments

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I use GNU-parallel to call a function `foo` repeatedly. The function takes two arguments, a filename (`a` in the example below, saved in the array `A`) and an array of filters (`B` below, with `b` as elements of `B`).

The function should iterate over all combinations of `A` and `B`, however, the catch is, that I actually use parallel only to iterate over `A`, while providing `B` to each function call.

As a minimum example:

```
#!/bin/bash

A=("1" "2" )
B=("X" "Y")

foo() {
    a=$1 # a single element of A
    B=$2 # the whole array B
    for b in "${B[@]}"; do
        printf "a = %s; b = %s\n" $a $b
    done
    echo "-----------------"
}
export -f foo

# goal:
echo "Sequential (aka, the target) ==="
for a in "${A[@]}"; do
    foo $a $B
done
```

Results

```
Sequential (aka, the target) ===
a = 1; b = X
a = 1; b = Y
-----------------
a = 2; b = X
a = 2; b = Y
-----------------
```

Mind that instead of having a single call to each combination, we have only for each `A` a call and then within the function iterate over `B`.

### Parallel tries:

#### Try 1

```
parallel foo ::: "${A[@]}" ::: "${B}"
```

Results in

```
a = 1; b = X
-----------------
a = 2; b = X
-----------------
```

(missing the second argument of B)

#### Try 2

```
parallel foo ::: "${A[@]}" ::: "${B[@]}"
```

Results in

```
a = 1; b = X
-----------------
a = 1; b = Y
-----------------
a = 2; b = X
-----------------
a = 2; b = Y
-----------------
```

(one call per combination, not one call per A, then iterating over B)

I have looked through the manual and SO but couldn't find a solution.

## Edit

I have the feeling that it should work when I export the array B directly, but get no results as well

```
foo2() {
    a=$1 # a single element of A
    # B=$2 # the whole array B
    for b in "${B[@]}"; do
        printf "a = %s; b = %s\n" $a $b
    done
    echo "-----------------"
}
export -f foo2
export B

parallel foo ::: "${A[@]}"
```

Results in

```
-----------------
-----------------
```

(apparently empty B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem stems from `B` being an array. I have never seen an array being passed as an argument to a function before, and I am not sure it can be done.

The second issue is that while you can export both functions and variables,  you cannot export an array without cheating: [Exporting an array in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564418/exporting-an-array-in-bash-script)

GNU Parallel makes it easy to cheat by using `env_parallel`. This will export the full environment to the shell running the command: Arrays, variables, aliases, and functions. It will even do so when running commands remotely.

`env_parallel` has improved a lot the past year, so upgrade if the version you have causes problems.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                        

A=("1" "2" )
B=("X" "Y")

foo() {
    a=$1 # a single element of A                                                   
#    B=$2 # the whole array B                                                      
    for b in "${B[@]}"; do
        printf "a = %s; b = %s\n" $a $b
    done
    echo "-----------------"
}

# If you have earlier run 'env_parallel --install'                                 
# to activate env_parallel in your shell                                           
# this should work.                                                                
env_parallel foo ::: "${A[@]}"

# If you have not, then this should work:
. `which env_parallel.bash`
env_parallel foo ::: "${A[@]}"
```