# Why is this Bash script not inheriting all environment variables?

Tags: bash

I'm trying something very straightforward:

```
PEOPLE=(
  "nick"
  "bob"
)
export PEOPLE="$(IFS=, ; echo "${PEOPLE[*]}")"
echo "$PEOPLE"  # prints 'nick,bob'
./process-people.sh
```

For some reason, `process-people.sh` isn't seeing `$PEOPLE`. As in, if I `echo "$PEOPLE"` from inside `process-people.sh`, it prints an empty line.

From what I understand, the child process created by invoking `./process-people.sh` should inherit all the parent process's environment variables, including `$PEOPLE`. 
 Yet, I've tried this on both Bash 3.2.57(1)-release and 4.2.46(2)-release and it doesn't work.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a neat solution you have there for [joining the elements of a Bash array into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9429887/877069). Did you know that in Bash you [cannot export array variables to the environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5564589/877069)? And if a variable is not in the environment, then the child process will not see it.

Ah. But you aren't exporting an array, are you. You're converting the array into a string and then exporting that. So it should work.

But this is Bash! Where various accidents of history conspire to give you the finger.

As @PesaThe and @chepner pointed out in the comments below, **you cannot actually convert a Bash array variable to a string variable**. According to the [Bash reference on arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html):

> Referencing an array variable without a subscript is equivalent to referencing with a subscript of 0.

So when you call `export PEOPLE=...` where `PEOPLE` was previously assigned an array value, what you're actually doing is `PEOPLE[0]=...`. Here's a fuller example:

```
PEOPLE=(
  "nick"
  "bob"
)
export PEOPLE="super"
echo "$PEOPLE"  # masks the fact that PEOPLE is still an array and just prints 'super'
echo "${PEOPLE[*]}"  # prints 'super bob'
```

It's unfortunate that the `export` silently fails to export the array to the environment (it returns `0`), and it's confusing that Bash equates `ARRAY_VARIABLE` to `ARRAY_VARIABLE[0]` in certain situations. We'll just have to chalk that up to a combination of history and backwards compatibility.

Here's a working solution to your problem:

```
PEOPLE_ARRAY=(
  "nick"
  "bob"
)
export PEOPLE="$(IFS=, ; echo "${PEOPLE_ARRAY[*]}")"
echo "$PEOPLE"  # prints 'nick,bob'
./process-people.sh
```

**The key here is to assign the array and derived string to different variables.** Since `PEOPLE` is a proper string variable, it will export just fine and `process-people.sh` will work as expected.

It's not possible to directly change a Bash array variable into a string variable. Once a variable is assigned an array value, it becomes an array variable. The only way to change it back to a string variable is to destroy it with `unset` and recreate it.

Bash has a couple of handy commands for inspecting variables that are useful for investigating these kinds of issues:

```
printenv PEOPLE  # prints 'nick,bob'
declare -p PEOPLE_ARRAY  # prints: declare -ax PEOPLE_ARRAY='([0]="nick" [1]="bob")'
```

`printenv` will only return a value for environment variables, vs. `echo`, which will print a result whether the variable has been properly exported or not.

`declare -p` will show the full value of a variable, without the gotchas related to including or leaving out array index references (e.g. `ARRAY_VARIABLE[*]`).

Comment: `Referencing an array variable without a subscript is equivalent to referencing with a subscript of 0.` So all that `PEOPLE=$(...)` did was assign the result of the command substitution to `PEOPLE[0]`. So there is no conversion, it's still an array that cannot be exported :)

Comment: @PesaThe - Not sure what you're referring to. Is there a specific line of code I wrote that doesn't work the way I said it would?

Comment: Ah, you're saying that the assignment of a string to an array variable just populates the 0-index of the array. Correct? So even if I do `export PEOPLE="some string"`, it will only overwrite the 0-index of the `PEOPLE` array?

Comment: @NickChammas Right; once the array attribute on a name is set, assigning to the name alone will always assign to the 0th element of the array. You can't unset the array attribute (short of unsetting the name itself).

Comment: PesaThe and chepner - Thank you. Even when I think I have the answer, SO goes deeper and shows me the shallowness of my knowledge.  I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: You can even see the minimal change necessary to turn a regular variable into an array. (This isn't strictly related to the question, but it's fun to watch happen, for some extremely minimal value of "fun".) After `x=3`, run `declare -p x` to see that it is a regular variable. Then run `declare -a x` followed by `declare -p x`. You'll see that the former value of `x` is now the value of the 0th element of the array `x`.