# how to set JVM property line.separator to newline from bash

Tags: bash, scala, newline, interpolation, jvm-arguments

I want to set JVM System property `line.separator` to a single newline on Windows (it's already a single newline by default everywhere else).

This scala script is used to display the effective line.separator property:

```
#!/usr/bin/env scala
val bytes = sys.props("line.separator").map { _.toInt }.mkString(" ")
printf("line.separator bytes: %s\n",bytes)
```

On a windows JVM, it normally prints the following:

```
line.separator bytes: 13 10
```

Briefly, I'm looking for a way to launch my test script so that it prints the following output:

```
line.separator bytes: 10
```

I can achive this with the following JAVA_OPTS setting:

```
export JAVA_OPTS=-Dline.separator=$'\n'
```

but only if I also modify the standard scala script by surrounding $JAVA_OPTS with double quotes.  Here's the section near the end of the scala script verbatim (i.e., WITHOUT the needed modification):

```
execCommand \
  "${JAVACMD:=java}" \
  $JAVA_OPTS \
  "${java_args[@]}" \
  "${classpath_args[@]}" \
  -Dscala.home="$SCALA_HOME" \
  $OVERRIDE_USEJAVACP \
  $WINDOWS_OPT \
   scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner  "$@"
```

With these two modifications, the test script above prints the following:

```
$ reportLineSeparator.sc
line.separator bytes: 10
```

Adding quotes to JAVA_OPTS is not a viable option, however, since that would prevent it from being unset, or from specifying multiple settings.

So the requirement seems to be to somehow arrange for the unquoted JAVA_OPTS to be correctly handled without losing the encoded newline.

I'm starting to suspect that there is solution, although I'm hopeful that someone will prove me wrong.

Update: it seems that if a bash array is used instead of JAVA_OPTS, that would provide a solution, since it could be quoted in the scala script.   In other words, replace the unquoted $JAVA_OPTS above with this:

```
"${JAVA_OPTS_ARR[@]}" \
```

I was pleasantly surprised that it also doesn't cause problems when JAVA_OPTS_ARR is undefined.

However, this isn't a viable solution because it's not possible to export bash arrays (see [Exporting an array in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564418/exporting-an-array-in-bash-script))

Follow-up: after further thinking about this problem, I concluded that interpolation isn't the issue.   The quotes are needed to contain the variable as a single command line argument.  So that raises the question as to whether the Internal Field Separator (IFS) could be used to keep the entire line.separator definition as a single command line argument without quotes.

Okay, it seems that if I add the following to the scala launch script, the line.separator setting seems to take effect:

```
IFS=' '
```

I can then append to JAVA_OPTS like this and get the desired behavior:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "-Dline.separator=$'\n'
```

The IFS setting has to occur prior to where the unquoted $JAVA_OPTS occurs.

Update: this invocation, suggested by @som-snytt seems to work:

```
scala -J-Dline.separator=$'\n' -nc lineSeparatorBytes.sc
```

Comment: `scala -J-Dline.separator=$'\r'$'\n'` seems to work because of `java_args`.

Comment: doesn't work for me in a cygwin bash shell, although it's somewhat more challenging to determine whether it worked because you're setting to the default setting for Windows JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JAVA_OPTS` is an ancient convention but not a standard. It was introduced to the `scala` script in 2007 and overtaken by `-J` in 2010.

I think the best option (so to speak) is `scala -J-Dline.separator=$'\r'$'\n'`.

There is a PR now for your suggestion, which seems safe, except it also keeps tab for the case:

`JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx256m <tab> -Xss1m"`.

Shell quoting is so much fun! I try to refresh my scarred memory every five years or so.

Edit: the answer was that passing the line.separator to Scala's background compile server broke. There are several issues with the compile server (which can be invoked with `fsc` for the "fast" scala compiler), which is now deprecated. The solution here, as always, is to use the `-nc` to request "no compile daemon" for your script. Compilation of the script takes a second longer, but you save hours or days of debugging.

Comment: your best option seems to get me into the REPL, but if I pass a script path, if fails with 'Usage: fsc <options> ...'.   Are you testing in a cygwin bash environment?

Comment: Your -nc invocation suggestion works for me, if you write it up I'll mark your response as the solution.

Comment: OK cool, that's weird enough to deserve an answer on SO. Personally, I gave up on fsc a long time ago and always use `-nc` (which is now a deprecated option because it is the default behavior).