# How to pass an array and an associative array between bash scripts?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I want to pass an array and an associative array between bash script.

I tried to send the argument as in the example bellow, but I get the erro message:

./b.sh: line 3: ${1[@]}: bad substitution

How can I do this?

Example:

First script a.sh that call other script b.sh

a.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/bash -x

declare -a array=("a" "b")
declare -A associative_array
associative_array[10]="Hello world"

./b.sh "${array[@]}" $associative_array
```

b.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

declare -a array="${1[@]}"
declare -A associative_array="$2"
echo "${array[@]}"
echo "${associative_array[10]}"
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo  No, this was the error message.

Comment: Sorry, I missed half your question so I deleted that comment. :-) Both arrays gets instantiated in my answer though.

Comment: You may consider `source ./b.sh` so that b.sh has direct access to both arrays.

Comment: There are 122 Q/A when searching for `[bash] pass associative array` . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564418/exporting-an-array-in-bash-script/21941473#21941473 looks to have answers that directly relate to your problem. Please learn to search first . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be flame-bait since it uses the evil `eval`, but you may find it useful until a better solution comes along. Don't use it without reading *[Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead)* first.

**a.sh**

```
declare -a array=("a" "b")
declare -A associative_array
associative_array[10]="Hello world"

./b.sh "$(declare -p array)" "$(declare -p associative_array)"
```

**b.sh**

```
eval "$1"
eval "$2"

echo "${array[@]}"
echo "${associative_array[10]}"
```