# Passing arrays as arguments via nameref attributes

Tags: bash

The whole idea is to find a way to pass multiple arrays as arguments to a script, which will use them accordingly. Playing around this idea, I have managed to safely create a function which does this:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo (){

    local -n a1=$1
    local -n a2=$2
  
    for i in "${a1[@]}"
    do
     echo $i
    done

    for i in "${a2[@]}"
    do
     echo $i
    done
    
}
array_1=( "on" "/path/to/me" "123" )
array_2=( "Green" "Red" )

foo array_1 array_2
```

When this function is called, the output is as expected:

```
$ ./foo.sh
on
/path/to/me
123
Green
Red
```

Now, I would like to produce a similar output but passing the arrays as arguments of a script, i.e.

```
$ declare -a array_1=( "on" "/path/to/me" "123" )
$ declare -a array_2=( "Green" "Red" )
$ ./funct.sh array_1 array_2
```

However I have not yet found the way. I have tried multiple options, such as

```
#!/bin/bash

foo2 (){

    local -n a1=$1
    local -n a2=$2
    
    for i in "${a1[@]}"
    do
     echo $i
    done
    
}

foo2 $1 $2
```

Update 1: Using `declare -n` does not seem to make any effect

```
   #!/bin/bash
   declare -n a1=$1
   declare -n a2=$2

    for i in "${a1[@]}"
    do
        echo $i
    done
```

Any ideas? Is this possible at all?

Comment: Running your script with an expclit `#!/bin/bash`, will create a new sub-shell process, that has no view into the arrays you created with `declare`

Comment: You'd need to `export` the array, but ["There isn't really a good way to encode an array
variable into the environment."](https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg01774.html). You're basically left to create your very own encoding/decoding strategy.

Comment: Also worth reading [Exporting an array in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5564418/5291015)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `source` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -n a1=$1
declare -n a2=$2

for i in "${a1[@]}" "${a2[@]}"
do  
    echo $i
done
```

Now in your interactive shell :

```
$ declare -a array_1=( "on" "/path/to/me" "123" )
$ declare -a array_2=( "Green" "Red" )
$ (source ./funct.sh array_1 array_2) # Run in subshell to not pollute your current shell session
```

will output :

```
on
/path/to/me
123
Green
Red
```

Comment: Yes, sourcing would work although it was not my intention.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your requirements ?

Comment: declare -a array_1=( "on" "/path/to/me" "123" ); declare -a array_2=( "Green" "Red" );   declare -a array_3=.... ;./funct.sh array_1 array_2 array_3 ....