# Search and replace variables in a file using bash/sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to write a bash script(script.sh) to search and replace some variables in input.sh file. But I need to modify only the variables which are present in variable_list file and leave others as it is.

### variable_list

```
${user}  
${dbname}
```

### input.sh

```
username=${user}  
password=${password}  
dbname=${dbname}
```

### Expected output file

```
username=oracle  
password=${password} > This line won't be changed as this variable(${password}) is not in variable_list file
dbname=oracle
```

Following is the script I am trying to use but I am not able to find the correct sed expression

### script.sh

```
export user=oracle  
export password=oracle123  
export dbname=oracle

variable='variable_list'  
while read line ;  
do  
 if [[ -n $line ]]     
 then  
  sed -i 's/$line/$line/g' input.sh > output.sh  
 fi  
done < "$variable"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could work:

```
#!/bin/bash

export user=oracle  
export password=oracle123  
export dbname=oracle

variable='variable_list'  
while read line ;  
do  
 if [[ -n $line ]]
 then
  exp=$(sed -e 's/\$/\\&/g' <<< "$line")
  var=$(sed -e 's/\${\([^}]\+\)}/\1/' <<< "$line")
  sed -i "s/$exp/${!var}/g" input.sh
 fi  
done < "$variable"
```

The first `sed` expression escapes the $ which is a regex metacharacter.  The second extracts just the variable name, then we use indirection to get the value in our current shell and use it in the `sed` expression.

**Edit**

Rather than rewriting the file so many times, it's probably more efficient to do it like this, building the arguments list for `sed`:

```
#!/bin/bash

export user=oracle  
export password=oracle123  
export dbname=oracle

while read var
do
    exp=$(sed -e 's/\$/\\&/g' <<< "$var")
    var=$(sed -e 's/\${\([^}]\+\)}/\1/' <<< "$var")
    args+=("-e s/$exp/${!var}/g")
done < "variable_list"

sed "${args[@]}" input.sh > output.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script.sh that works:

```
#!/bin/bash

user=oracle
password=oracle123
dbname=oracle

variable='variable_list'
text=$(cat input.sh)
while read line
do
  value=$(eval echo $line)  
  text=$(sed "s/$line/$value/g" <<< "$text")
done < "$variable"
echo "$text" > output.sh
```

Note that your original version contains single quotes around the sed string, which doesn't insert the value of `$line`. It is trying to look for the literal `line` after the end of the line `$` (which will never find anything).

Since you are looking for the value of the variable in `$line`, you need to do an eval to get this.

Also, since there are multiple variables you are looping over, the intermediate `text` variable stores the result as it loops.

The `export` keyword is also [unnecessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/bash-defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export) in this script, unless it is being used in some sub-process not shown.

Answer (score 2):

```
user=oracle  
password=oracle123  
dbname=oracle

variable_list=( '${user}' '${dbname}' )

while IFS="=$IFS" read variable value; do
    for subst_var in "${variable_list[@]}"; do
        if [[ $subst_var = $value ]]; then
            eval "value=$subst_var"
            break
        fi
    done
    printf "%s=%s\n" "$variable" "$value"
done < input.sh > output.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

TXR solution. Build a filter dynamically. The filter is implemented internally as a trie data structure, which gives us a `lex`-like state machine which matches the entire dictionary at once as the input is scanned. For simplicity, we include the `${` and `}` as part of the variable name.

```
@(bind vars (("${user}" "oracle")
             ("${dbname}" "oracle")
             ("${password}" "letme1n")))
@(next "variable_list")
@(collect)
@entries
@(end)
@(deffilter subst . @(mapcar (op list @1 (second [find vars @1 equal first]))
                             entries))
@(next "input.sh")
@(collect)
@line
@  (output :filter subst)
@line
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr subst.txr
username=oracle
password=${password}
dbname=oracle
```

`input.sh:` (as given)

```
username=${user}
password=${password}
dbname=${dbname}
```

`variable_list:` (as given)

```
${user}
${dbname}
```

Comment: `(mapcar (op list @1 (second [find vars @1 equal first])) entries)` means "map the elements of `entries` through a function which forms a two-element list consisting of the variable, and the result of substituting that variable in the `var` list." `[find vars @1 equal first]` means find argument 1 of the anonymous function (the entry) among `vars` using `equal` as the comparison (works with strings), and using the `first` of each entry as the key (since the entries are two-element lists, the first being the key).  `find` returns the pair and so `(second ...)` gets the value.