# Bash Programming Passing Argument

Tags: bash

I am currently learning bash programming and dont really understand why the passing argument for me is not working.

i have a script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
# the following environment variables must be set before running this script
# SIM_DIR name of directory containing armsim
# TEST_DIR name of the directory containing this script and the expected outputs
# LOG_DIR name of the directory that your output is written to by the run_test2 script
# ARMSIM_VERBOSE set to "-v" for verbose logging or leave unset

# First check the environment variables are set
giveup=0
if [[ ${#SIM_DIR} -eq 0 || ${#TEST_DIR} -eq 0 || ${#LOG_DIR} -eq 0 ]] ; then
    echo One or more of the following environment variables must be set:
    echo SIM_DIR, TEST_DIR, LOG_DIR
    giveup=1
fi

# Now check the verbose flag
if [[ ${#ARMSIM_VERBOSE} != 0 && "x${ARMSIM_VERBOSE}" != "x-v" ]] ; then
    echo ARMSIM_VERBOSE must be unset, empty or set to -v
    giveup=1
fi

# Stop if environment is not set up
if [ ${giveup} -eq 1 ] ; then
    exit 0
fi

cd ${TEST_DIR}
for i in test2-*.sh; do
  echo "**** Running test ${i%.sh} *****"
  ./$i > ${LOG_DIR}/${i%.sh}.log
done
```

When I run the .sh file and pass in 3 example argument as below:-

`$ ./run_test2 SIM_DIR TEST_DIR LOG_DIR`

It still show: `One or more of the following environment variables must be set:
SIM_DIR, TEST_DIR, LOG_DIR`

Can anyone guide me on this? Thank you.

Comment: Do you even set the environment variables?

Comment: Environment variables aren't really arguments in the sense I understand from your question/example. It sounds to me like you want to give arguments to a function/script, if you do that you can find your arguments in $1-9 (I think bash supports even more, unsure), the number of arguments are stored in $#.

Comment: @Jite - Right. Sounds like you could flesh that out into another answer. One which uses arguments, instead of environment variables.

Comment: @ArjunShankar - Just did, with a simple example, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how it's intended to work. The environment variables must be set beforehand either in the script or in the terminal like

```
export SIM_DIR=/home/someone/simulations
export TEST_DIR=/home/someone/tests
export LOG_DIR=/home/someone/logs

./run_test2
```

If you use these variables frequently, you might want to `export` them in `~/.bashrc`. The syntax is identical to the `export`s in the above example.

Comment: @Alan Curry Where and why is it necessary?

Comment: `export SIM_DIR=/home/someon/simulations` - if you don't export it, it's just a shell variable in the current shell, not an environment variable

Comment: @Deve - Unless exported, a variable is not available in sub-processes. This means, unless you `export` it, even though bash sees `SIM_DIR`, the script won't. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/bash-defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export)

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables aren't really arguments in the sense I understand from your question/example. It sounds to me like you want to give arguments to a function/script, if you do that you can find your arguments in $1-9 (I think bash supports even more, unsure), the number of arguments are stored in $#

Example function that expects two arguments:

```
my_func() {
    if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
        printf "You need to give 2 arguments\n"
        return
    fi

    printf "Your first argument: %s\n" "$1"
    printf "Your second argument: $s\n" "$2"
}

# Call the functionl like this
my_func arg1 arg2
```