# Load Error on Ruby 1.9.3 Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, osx-mountain-lion

I am new to Ruby and just installed Ruby 1.9.3. on my Moutnain Lion MacOSx with RVM and Homebrew.

After I installed Ruby, I wrote my first Tutorial Program (with text, textmate and Tincta) and saved it as a file.rb.
Now the problem is that i get this error message:

```
users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ ruby calc.rb
ruby: No such file or directory -- calc.rb (LoadError)
```

The brew doctor command gives me this, but I don't even know if this has something to do with the issue:

```
Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:

    bashbug
    gcov-4.2
    git
    git-cvsserver
    git-receive-pack
    git-shell
    git-upload-archive
    git-upload-pack
    gitk
```

Consider amending your PATH so that `/usr/local/bin`
occurs before `/usr/bin` in your PATH.
Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your path.
Consider amending your PATH variable so it contains:

```
/usr/local/sbin
```

Comment: I warmly recommend you to use https://rvm.io/ instead of homebrew.

Comment: i have RVM istalled but homebrew too, Shall i remove homebrew ? But i doubt that this is the solution for the load error ...

Comment: No, you should not remove homebrew, just remove the ruby package with homebrew and use rvm instead for ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby is complaining that it can't find `calc.rb`. According to your description, you saved the file as file.rb, and then you tried to run calc.rb. Try `ruby file.rb`.

If that doesn't work, verify that ruby is working with

```
echo "puts 'hello'" | ruby
```

It should output `hello`. Then try running it from a file:

```
echo "puts 'hello'" > test.rb
ruby test.rb
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It all works fine the way you explained it. But still the problem is that when i use a text edit tool like  text, textmate and Tincta ... and save it on my desktop it doesn't get found by ruby. Am i supposed to save files to a special location ?

Comment: Ok, if you're saving the files on the desktop, in the terminal you need to `cd ~/Desktop` before running ruby

Comment: Thanks so much Tom. It can be so simple somethimes ;-) Cheer Buddy, head ache just stopped

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to troubleshoot from within your shell:

1 - Verify `calc.rb` exists:

```
ls calc.rb  # will complain if calc.rb doesn't exist in the current directory
```

2 - Check where the `ruby` executable is being found:

```
which ruby  # this might help narrow down issues with your $PATH
```

With regard to the homebrew issue, see if any of the following help:

- [brew doctor says “Error: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin” how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11335908/2004045)
- [Where does $PATH get set in OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard?](https://superuser.com/a/69190) - still relevant in Mountain Lion AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks very much ! I needed to change directories to make ruby find the file.