# How do I install Ruby without using RVM on OS X?

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I have some issues with upgrading my Ruby version with RVM on OS X.

RMV uses MacPorts, causing me to run `sudo port selfupdate`, which gets a bunch of compiling errors, despite correct Xcode command line tools installed.

I found some installation instructions using Linux `apt-get` but unfortunately I don't have in it on my Mac.

I want to install Ruby without RVM. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have Homebrew? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287882/installing-ruby-with-homebrew

Comment: RVM has a [whole page in its docs for MacPorts integration](http://rvm.io/integration/macports).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall thank you but I know about this page, and I always get the same error : `command failed: cd /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base && CC=/usr/bin/cc ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --with-tclpackage=/Library/Tcl --with-install-user=root --with-install-group=admin --with-directory-mode=0755 --enable-readline && make && make install SELFUPDATING=1
Exit code: 2
DEBUG: Error installing new MacPorts base:...Error: /opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Error installing new MacPorts base: command execution failed`

Comment: @superEb I think it is the best way to do, I knew about `MacPorts` having some compatibility pb with `Lion``, and their official instructions don't do the trick for me. Thanks, I think I 'll use `rbenv`, which a `rvm`-like tool. Perpahs, you should consider edit your post as the answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case Macports does not work for you, try Homebrew:

```
rvm autolibs homebrew
```

Please note: Although it is not required, you might want to install Homebrew before using it with autolibs. It keeps Homebrew out of RVM directories.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/), you can either [install and manage a single version of Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287882/installing-ruby-with-homebrew):

```
brew update
brew install ruby
```

Or, even better, use [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) as a flexible alternative to RVM:

```
brew update
brew install rbenv
brew install ruby-build
rbenv install 2.0.0-p247
rbenv rehash
```

rbenv then makes it easy to use a specific version of Ruby either [globally](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#rbenv-global) or [per project](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#rbenv-local) (which can then be added to source control).

Note that you *may* want to follow the advice from rbenv's "caveats" (`brew info rbenv`), particularly the part about adding `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to your profile.

Comment: `brew install ruby` is all I ever want for my simple Ruby needs - I just use Ruby 2 for nanoc and the odd sysadmin script. I can easily update if necessary, and can aslo just dump all of Homebrew and its installs in one go if I ever need to. I used rvm for a couple of years, but it was way too much overkill and a little too problematic an install on new machines for my liking.