# Reverting back to Ruby 2.0.0 without RVM

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems

I recently installed the latest version of Ruby which is 2.4.1 to run a script that required a gem called prawn. Now, I installed ruby using Homebrew and did the export path within ~/.bash_profile, however, removing the $PATH statement is not allowing me to revert back to 2.0.0 (system default) any idea, how, or why.

What I did try doing was uninstalling ruby with homebrew, (the latest version) however, that just removed ruby all together; using ruby -v would say there was no ruby actually installed despite the fact that 2.0.0 is still there.

`ruby -v` returns ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16]

`which ruby` returns `/usr/local/bin/ruby`

`whereis ruby` returns `/usr/bin/ruby`

`echo $PATH` returns `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

SOLVED. Used `brew unlink ruby`

Comment: Most common reason: your $PATH is still wrong. Basic commands for troubleshooting: `which ruby`, and `echo $PATH`. If you need more help then please post the results of those commands here too.

Comment: `which ruby` gives me /usr/local/bin/ruby

Comment: `echo $PATH` gives me /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: What $PATH statement did you remove?  you may need to launch a new shell/terminal window to reflect the change.  Editing the .bash_profile won't magically change your existing window.

Comment: Joe, I did, I even restarted my laptop and used the source .bash_profile. The $PATH statement I used in the first place was to get the latest version to work correctly, see here:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287882/installing-ruby-with-homebrew)

Comment: I've solved it anyways, had to use `brew unlink ruby` Thanks anyways.

Comment: You can answer & accept your own question, that way it doesn't appear unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

Just unlinked homebrew from Ruby by using `brew unlink ruby`.