# Ruby version not updating after install

Tags: ruby

I successfully installed ruby version to 2.7, but `ruby -v` doesn't want to update. See output below:

```
➜  ~ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]
```

Verify that Ruby 2.7 has been installed:

```
➜  ~ brew install ruby@2.7                        
Warning: ruby@2.7 2.7.6_1 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 2.7.6_1, run:
  brew reinstall ruby@2.7
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I am confused. What does this have to do with Kotlin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Ruby with Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287882/installing-ruby-with-homebrew)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `which ruby` to find out where it's getting that executable from.

```
$ which ruby
/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
```

homebrew will put it in `/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/ruby` as shown there, but if that's not in your path then it will get the system ruby.

```
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

In that case you need to add the homebrew ruby bin directory to your `PATH`. I have this in my `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [@Kyle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12287926/17771995)

Assume my Mac uses Zshell, it works for me.

1. find `.zshrc` file, add this line below and then save it.

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
```

2. run in terminal

```
source ~/.zshrc
```