# python - os.getenv and os.environ don't see environment variables of my bash shell

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables, pythonpath

I am on ubuntu 13.04, bash, python2.7.4

**The interpreter doesn't see variables I set.**

Here is an example:

```
$ echo $A
5
$ python -c 'import os; print os.getenv( "A" )'
None
$ python -c 'import os; print os.environ[ "A" ]'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'A'
```

But everything works fine with the `PATH` variable:

```
$ echo $PATH 
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
$ python -c 'import os; print os.getenv("PATH")'
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

And it notices changes in `PATH`:

```
$ PATH="/home/alex/tests/:$PATH"
$ echo $PATH 
/home/alex/tests/:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
$ python -c 'import os; print os.getenv("PATH")'
/home/alex/tests/:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

What could be wrong?

PS  the problem comes when using `$PYTHONPATH`:

```
$ python -c 'import os; print os.getenv("PYTHONPATH")'
None
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Aha! the solution is simple!

I was setting variables with plain `$ A=5` command; when you use `$ export B="foo"` everything is fine.

That is [beca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/bash-defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export)[use](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Environment.html#Environment) `export` makes the variable available to sub-processes:

- it creates a variable in the shell
- and *exports* it into the environment of the shell
- the environment is passed to sub-processes of the shell.

Plain `$ A="foo"` just creates variables in the shell and doesn't do anything with the environment.

The interpreter called from the shell obtains its environment from the parent -- the shell. So really the variable should be exported into the environment before.

Comment: `environment` is not code, so it should not be code-formatted.

Answer (score 9):

Those variables (parameters in bash terminology) are not *environment* variables. You want to export them into the environment, using `export` or `declare -x`. See the [bash documentation on environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Environment.html#Environment).

Comment: hey! terminology is vague: http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables

Comment: Not sure which term you're complaining about, but the issue lies with bash. Python has no control over which variables bash puts in the environment.

Comment: I mean that if it is a "parameter" or "variable" -- doesn't matter to me. I care about setting `PYTHONPATH` to work. Though, I see your point -- you mean that assignment `$ A=5` doesn't make an environment variable at all. There is a list of variables in the shell, called "environment". It is passed to sub-processes. And `export` declares some variables in that list (exports them into it). Plain assignment doesn't create variables in that list -- it puts them somewhere else. I'll correct my answer according to all of this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding as I do not see an answer that has the exact issue I had. If you have multiple "shells" eg BASH and Z-Shell, ensure that you have exported the environment in the correct shell and that this is available to python.

If you are using VSCode and set the default shell to Z shell, then understandably, variables in `.bashrc` will not be visible to the python interpreter if they do not also exist in `.zshrc`. The solution then is to `export` the variable in both shells or change the default shell to the one with the necessary variables.

Answer (score 0):

As @NelsonGon points out, this problem may occur if you set the environment variable in shell window A but then start Python from shell window B, because window B doesn't know anything about window A's environment.

One solution outlined [in this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/qw6msy/cant_see_my_environment_variable_when_using/) is to use a Python library called `python-dotenv` to load a small environment file into the Python environment you're using.

To quote their answer (with minor edits):

1. Install python-dotenv

```bash
pip install python-dotenv
```

2. Make a file in your python project directory called `.env`
3. Open it with your editor (nano, vim, etc.) and add secrets to it like so:

`MY_SECRET_KEY="12345"`
`SOME_OTHER_SECRET="45678"`

4. Then in your python code, you can write the following and it will work.

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv() # you can specify a location to your .env file as an argument if it's not at your project root

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('MY_SECRET_KEY')
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35598100)