# Updated environment variable but os.getenv() keeps returning None

Tags: python, python-3.x, getenv

I can't seem to get my code to respond to custom environment variables  so I wrote a piece of code to test it. `os.getenv` is not pulling the environment variables that I've set in BASH into my Python code.

```bash
$ FRUSTRATION="PYTHON!!"
$ echo $FRUSTRATION
PYTHON!!
$ ipython
In [1]: import os

In [2]: very_frustrated = os.getenv("FRUSTRATION")

In [3]: print(very_frustrated)
None
```

Comment: This is not the code you ran. `echo FRUSTRATION` without a leading `$` would repeat `FRUSTRATION`, not the contents of the variable. At a guess, you didn't actually `export FRUSTRATION` in the shell you launched `ipython` from.

Comment: Can't recreate this. Are you launching `ipython` from the same shell?

Comment: Which operating system / shell? That doesn't look like any linux shell I know of.

Comment: In many linux shells, `!!` is a shortcut for the previous command. If you simply meant it for emphasis, a different method would be good.

Comment: Had a similar issue within Jupyter notebook. Just had to restart Jupyter (not just the kernel).

Comment: The issue is that the environment variable wasn't `exported`. You just need to write: `export FRUSTRATION="PYTHON!!"` and it will work. This is a duplicate of [python - os.getenv and os.environ don't see environment variables of my bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19070615/1164465).

Comment: It can be that you set the variable in a different shell. For example setting the variable in `zsh` and then running the python script from `bash` the variable won't show up in os.environ

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Works for me:

```
:: export FOO=boo
:: python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 18:31:42)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.getenv('FOO')
'boo'
>>>
```

My guess is that you either forgot to export the variable, or you spelled the variable wrong.

Answer (score 15):

```
print os.environ
```

Do this to see if you have environment var added to you system or not.
Your python code is fine. It's the problem setting env var.

Comment: I don't see how this is any better than just calling `os.getenv`. If its a problem setting the variable, this change doesn't help.

Comment: @tdelaney It would show the variables you could see, and potentially see the variable you're looking for--except the name might be spelled wrong or something of that nature.  I happen to think it is a valuable debugging step, but it's not a real answer to the problem.