# Why does python not see the environment variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables

In the terminal, I have exported my API key the following way:

```
export ALPHAVANTAGE_KEY=XXXXXXXXXX
```

In the console, when I type 'env' I get amongst other things :

```
ALPHAVANTAGE_KEY=XXXXXXXXXX
```

But in my code, the following prints 'None' :

```
print(os.environ.get('ALPHAVANTAGE_KEY'))
```

Why is that ?

Comment: Did you start the python process from the same shell where you exported the environment variable, after setting it? Environment inheritance happens when a child process is created.

Comment: See this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070615/python-os-getenv-and-os-environ-dont-see-environment-variables-of-my-bash-she

Comment: I have created the env variable from Pycharm Terminal and then ran the program via Pycharm. Is that not ok ? 

Also I've tried to test what happens if I close pycharm and re-open it but in that case the variable disappears from the list when I check with 'env'

Comment: run the script by hand from a terminal, rather than using Pycharm's console.

Comment: Env vars are not global. They are per-process and when a process (like your shell or pycharm) starts another process it usually gives the new process a copy of its env vars. So changing the env vars in a shell does not affect the env vars of a different process (e.g., pycharm).

Comment: Or you can configure your "run configuration", set the envvar there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice way to manage the environment variables is with dotenv:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv  # pip install python-dotenv

load_dotenv("/Users/gerald/environment_variables/.env")
```

With the .env file looking like this :

```
ALPHAVANTAGE_KEY="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
NEWSAPI_KEY="YYYYYYYYYYYYY"
```

And then use the values this way :

```
"apikey": os.environ.get('NEWSAPI_KEY')
```