# mlint syntax checking in vim

Tags: bash, matlab, vim, environment-variables, mlint

I tried to get the MATLAB syntax checking to work in Vim.

I used [`Bundle 'jrestrepo/matlab'`](https://github.com/jrestrepo/matlab) and for syntax highlighting and it works fine. But the syntax checking doesn't work. I exported `/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/bin/maci64/` to `PATH` with:

```
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/bin/maci64
```

in my `bash_profile` and now on the command line I get:

```
Tierra-Gorda:~ mike$ which mlint
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/bin/maci64/mlint

Tierra-Gorda:~ mike$ mlint
dyld: Library not loaded: libtbb.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/bin/maci64/./libmwfl.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

and I suspect, that the dot in the path messes it up somehow. Because the file `libmwfl.dylib` exists in `.../maci64/libmwfl.dylib`.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I'm not a Mac user, but perhaps you should also set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Also worth checking out the output of `otool -L`

Comment: Please add your comment as answer and describe a little bit more, how you meant to use otool and which path to provide for future reference.
I think this solved it and as soon as I figured out, what exactly fixed it, I'll accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to set the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable in addition to `PATH`:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/bin/maci64
```

According to [`man dyld`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html):

> **DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH**
>
> This is a colon separated list of directories that contain libraries. The dynamic
>   linker searches these directories before it searches the default locations for
>   libraries. It allows you to test new versions of existing libraries.
>
> For each library that a program uses, the dynamic linker looks for it in each
>   directory in `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in turn. If it still can't find the library, it
>   then searches `DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH` and `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` in turn.
>
> Use the `-L` option to `otool(1)` to discover the frameworks and shared libraries
>   that the executable is linked against.

---

#### EDIT:

I think a safer way is to append to `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` instead. That way you don't take precedence over the default search path, and possibly override libraries loaded by other programs...

Even better, you should create a launcher script (where you set `DYLD_*` then start `mlint`), as opposed to changing the environment variables globally in your `bash_profile`.

Comment: As you feared, after having this in my bashrc, git refused to up/download repos. The reason seemed to be curl, which was not loaded in the poper version. Where would I do this launcher script? As a bash thing - how/when would I start it with mlint?
Or in vim,.. same questions.

Comment: just create a wrapper `my_mlint.sh` bash script inside your profile, where you set the appropriate environment variables and launch the actual `mlint` program (that way you don't pollute the global vars). You would then invoke this script from Vim instead of calling mlint directly... I feel like I should mentioned this again, but I'm mostly a Windows user and everything I suggested above is untested :)

Comment: But then again, I guess, that in this environment the variable is set and I'd need to open a new terminal to use the git curl version. I don't know enough about bash variables, but I guess this is saved in that session. There has to be a non intrusive solution somehow!

Comment: actually that's not an issue. Setting environment variables in a bash script that you execute does not affect those in the parent shell, only sub-processes that you launch from inside the script will see the modified vars. Note there is a difference between executing and sourcing a script. See this links for more info: http://superuser.com/q/176783/11293, http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/processtree, http://stackoverflow.com/q/1158091/97160

Comment: Very nice. Thank you. Since in vim mlint is called by a plugin and I'd rather not mess with plugins, such that they get rewritten each update, I tried the fallback path. This works! Nice info for both the solution and the scope of the variables.
I'd add a point, but can't by now^^. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I added carefully the correct paths to certain libraries on my .bash_profile

```
export matlabroot="/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app"

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib:${matlabroot}/bin/:${matlabroot}/runtime/maci64
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:${matlabroot}/sys/os/maci64:${matlabroot}/bin/maci64

DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:${matlabroot}/bin/maci64

export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Rerun Terminal or Vim and it should work now.
To give some credit, I found the answer here: 
[Issue on a Matlab 2010b on MacBook Pro (Lion)](http://wlee0204.appspot.com/page?m=agpzfndsZWUwMjA0chALEghCYXNlSXRlbRihnAEM)