# setting global variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have function where I am expecting it to hang sometime. So I am setting one global variable and then reading it, if it didn't come up after few second I give up. Below is not complete code but it's not working as I am not getting $START as value 5

```
START=0
ineer()
{
    sleep 5
    START=5
    echo "done $START"   ==> I am seeing here it return 5
    return $START
}
echo "Starting"
ineer &

while true
do
    if [ $START -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "Not null $START"  ==> But $START here is always 0
    else
        echo "else $START"
        break;
    fi
    sleep 1;
done
```

Comment: I suspect that running the function in the background causes it to be executed in a subshell, so the variable changes are not reflected in the parent shell.

Comment: timeout is exact fit for me but It did't take function as command

Comment: You may be interested in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87284/how-to-share-environment-variables-between-shells-like-globals-related-to-a-mast -- mind you, @user000001 is exactly right that `ineer` is executed in a subshell and doesn't share an environment with its parent shell, so what you're going to find there are workarounds (mostly involving files).

Comment: You might need to look at the `timeout` command from GNU coreutils.  You may also end up looking at signals (`trap` and `kill`) between child and parent processes.

Answer (score 12):

You run `inner` function call in back ground, which means the `START` will be assigned in a subshell started by current shell. And in that subshell, the `START` value will be 5.

However in your current shell, which `echo` the `START` value, it is still `0`. Since the update of `START` will only be in the subshell.

Each time you start a shell in background, it is just like fork a new process, which will make a copy of all current shell environments, including the variable value, and the new process will be completely isolate from your current shell.

Since the subshell have been forked as a new process, there is no way to directly update the parent shell's `START` value. Some alternative ways include  signals passing when the subshell which runs `inner` function exit.

### common errors:

#### `export`

`export` could only be used to make the variable name available to any subshells forked from current shell. however, once the subshell have been forked. The subshell will have a new copy of the variable and the value, any changes to the exported variable in the shell will not effect the subshell.

Please take the following code for details.

```
#!/bin/bash
export START=0
ineer()
{
    sleep 3
    export START=5
    echo "done $START"  # ==> I am seeing here it return 5
    sleep 1
    echo "new value $START"
    return $START
}
echo "Starting"
ineer &

while true
do
    if [ $START -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "Not null $START" #  ==> But $START here is always 0
        export START=10
        echo "update value to $START"
        sleep 3
    else
        echo "else $START"
        break;
    fi
    sleep 1;
done
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `ineer &` runs the function in a subshell, which is its own scope for variables. Changes made in a subshell will not apply to the parent shell. I recommend looking into [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) and signal catching.

Answer (score 1):

Save `pid` of `inner &` by:

```
pid=$!
```

and use `kill -0 $pid` (that is zero!!) to detect if your process still alive.

But better redesign `inner` to use lock file, this is safer check!

**UPDATE** From `KILL(2)` man page:

```
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <signal.h>

  int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);

If sig is 0, then no signal is sent, but error checking is still
performed; this can be used to check for the existence
of a process ID or process group ID.
```

Comment: Can you add more on this use kill -0 $pid (that is zero!!)

Answer (score -1):

The answer is: in this case you can use `export`. 
This instruction allow all subprocesses to use this variable.
So when you'll call the `ineer` function it will fork a process that is copying the entire environment, including the START variable taken from the parent process.

You have to change the first line from:

```
START=0
```

to:

```
export START=0
```

You may also want to read this thread: [Defining a variable with or without export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export)

Comment: export does not work, as it does not effect the subshell once the subshell have already been forked.