# unable to fetch environment varible in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I want to fetch some environment variable which are set in .bash_aliases file. I want use them in my bash script

```
#!/bin/dash
echo $PATH
echo $DEPOT_TOOLS
```

Both are coming empty string once call it in myscript. In the terminal these variable are printing successfully.

Comment: Could you add the lines that define the variables? Are they exported? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1158091/2424184

Comment: Why are you setting environment variables in a non-standard file intended to define aliases?

Comment: Are you using `bash` or `dash`?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is source the .bash_aliases file -- however as `dash` does only supports POSIX shell syntax you'll likely find that there are definitions inside of .bash_aliases that don't work for dash. If this is the case simply put your aliases inside of a different file and source that. Also the environment variable `PATH` is generally always available not sure what's going on with your system.

```
#!/bin/dash
. .some_aliases
echo "$PATH"
echo "$something_else"
```