# Substitute variables value in myscript.sh file when running with sh command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have a property file say mypropety.properties where i have set multiple key value pairs.

I load properties to the current session running `$. myproperty.properties` command.

Now when I run script using `$. myscript.sh` it loads all variable values from session and works fine. However in my use case I need to run the command using `sh myscript.sh` command and when I run it this way it doesn't replace variable values in the script and fails.

Any idea how to do variable substitution when running a script with sh command?

Comment: you just can't. That must be one of the meanings of the word "shell".

Comment: Do you export the variables in you properties file? i.e. `export key=value`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre then what's the way?

Comment: @heijp06 i just write `key=value`. It normally works when i run `. myscript.sh`

Comment: For the variable to be visible to sub processes you would have to export it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export

Answer (score 0):

Bash looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment and if present expands and reads the file.

```
sh -c "BASH_ENV=myproperty.properties myscript.sh"
```