# Tensorflow won't find libcublas.so.9.0 even though LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set

Tags: tensorflow

I have installed Cuda Toolkit 9.0 and cuDNN v7.0 according to instrucitons  on https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux (and nvidia site) instruction. However, when I try to run some script using tensorflow it says it cannot find it

`ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

even though my LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set correctly:

`echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/extras/CUPTI/lib64`

is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Did you try executing `sudo ldconfig`?

Comment: Have you restarted your environment (terminal)?

Comment: tried ldcofig, didnt help

Comment: I've set the variable only for current session in terminal so resetting it  will unset the variable

Comment: Maybe you just need `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...` rather than `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...`? [Only the former will affect subprocesses started by the shell.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export)

Comment: I did the export one

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed cuda with the runfile installation method you have to set also the `PATH` variable according to the [Nvidia documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#environment-setup).
I would recommend adding `export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}` and `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}`(64-bit) or `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}`(32-bit) to your `.bashrc` (if you use `bash`).