# Explain the different parts of the code needed to add $HOME/.rbenv/bin to your $PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-16.04

I understand the code is trying to make the executable in $HOME/.rbenv/bin available in $PATH so it can be executed from the command line but I can't figure out how the code does this. The code is shown below:

echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> $HOME/.bashrc.

I know that something is being appended to the end of the bashrc file and I know export is used to export environment variables to new shells but I don't see any new shell here. And I have seen echo used in the following way: a = 5; echo $a but I can't figure out why you need it here and what is

PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"

doing. what does 'PATH' represent. Is it a variable without the $ and what is 'bin:$PATH'.

Answer (score 0):

In bash (and most other shells) you assign variables without the `$`, so `PATH=something` assigns the variable `PATH` to the string `"something"`.

In Unix/ Linux, `PATH` is a string variable that contains a list of folders separated by colons (`:`). For example on my laptop this is my `PATH`:

```
> echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

This means that any executable in those folders is accessible anywhere without having to type the full path. You will typically add things to the `PATH` in your `.bashrc` file, so they get added when your shell starts up. If you use the `which` command you can see where a command lives, it will be in one of these folders:

```
> which rm
/bin/rm
```

To add a new folder to the `PATH`, you re-assign `PATH` to be a string of the new folder, followed by a colon and the previous value of `PATH`.

In you example, you are adding `$HOME/.rbenv/bin` to the start of `PATH`. `$HOME` will be expanded to your home directory.

To understand this better we can do something like this:

```
 > echo $PATH               
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
 > export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
 > echo $PATH                          
/Users/javanut13/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

As you can see the `rbenv` folder was added to the front of the `PATH` variable.

`export` puts the [variable into the environment of the current shell, which means that other commands started in that shell (subprocesses) also get this change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export). For example if you don't do `export` and then run a bash script that uses `ruby`, it will fail because it doesn't have the `~/.rbenv/bin` folder in its path.

Comment: Added that into the answer.

Comment: Can you point me to some resources to learn about linux I seem to have some core concepts confused in my head.

Comment: I don’t have any great suggestions, sorry.

Comment: Let's say you open up a new terminal does the system look first in bashrc or $PATH to find executables. They seem very similar to me.

Comment: When you open a terminal, it will start Bash, which will execute your `.bashrc` file, which sets the `PATH` (as you asked in your question). Then when you're using Bash, each time you run a command it will search through the `PATH` variable for executable files, and run the first match (or print an error if it cannot be found). So the `PATH` is entirely to do with Bash (or whichever shell) and doesn't matter to the system - when the "system" runs a command, it will use Bash (or a lighter-weight alternative) to first create a `PATH` and then run the command.