# Difference between export SOME_ENV_VAR=KEY and SOMEOTHER_ENV_VAR=KEY in dotenv?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

I am relatively new to Node.js. I want to export environment variables from .env file to my javascript files. In order to do that I am using dotenv.

Which method should I use to export the environment variables to my main javascript files ( say- app.js)

```
export GEOCODER_API_KEY= someKeyXYZ // inside .env file

GEOCODER_API_KEY_1 = someKeyXYZ // inside .env file
```

One thing to note is that upon console.log(process.env) in the app.js, the GEOCODER_API_KEY_1 shows up as env variable, but not GEOCODER_API_KEY? Why is that. What use is the first one then, since it is not accessible?
A more confusing thing is that:

```
var options = {
  provider: 'google',
  httpAdapter: 'https',
  apiKey: process.env.GEOCODER_API_KEY,
  formatter: null
};  // this works

... // some javascript
console.log(process.env.GEOCODER_API_KEY) //SHOWS UNDEFINED
```

I basically want to export the API_KEY (unrestricted) safely to my project. Is there a catch that I might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of writing portable variable declarations in an `.env` file is:

```
FOO=BAR
```

This is - when you use `dotenv` implementations like [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/blob/master/lib/main.js).

```
require('dotenv').config();

console.log(process.env);
```

When using export in `.env` in a Unix/Bash environment (what you have probably seen in the wild) - sourcing the file will yield [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export) concerning the scope of the declared variable:

```
# .env
export GEOCODER_API_KEY=someKeyXYZ
GEOCODER_API_KEY_1=someKeyXYZ
```

```
# main.sh

#!/bin/bash

. ./.env

./subprocess.sh
```

```
# subprocess.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "GEOCODER_API_KEY": $GEOCODER_API_KEY

echo "GEOCODER_API_KEY_1": $GEOCODER_API_KEY_1
```

```
./main.sh
GEOCODER_API_KEY: someKeyXYZ
GEOCODER_API_KEY_1:
```