# How to get ansible to update PATH

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to do:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/new/path/to/bin
```

in Ansible, if possible without using shell or command.

I've tried this

```
 - name: Add another bin dir to system-wide $PATH.
  copy:
    dest: /etc/profile.d/custom-path.sh
    content: 'PATH=$PATH:{{ my_custom_path_var }}'
```

That I got from:
https://www.jeffgeerling.com/comment/reply/2799

But it doesn't work as PATH results in:

```
\$PATH:/new/path/to/bin
```

breaking the system's PATH.

Comment: Your `PATH` probably doesn't need to be `export`:ed again; the system already does that, and then it will stay exported. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export

Answer (score 1):

Using shell or command would be:

```
  - name: Add pm2 to PATH
    shell: echo "PATH=$PATH:/new/path/to/bin" > /etc/environment
    become: true
```

But I'd still prefer an option that doesn't use shell/command.

Comment: variable expansion doesn't work in /etc/environment, this would break your setup

Answer (score 0):

Solution without using shell module
instead of

```
    content: 'PATH=$PATH:{{ my_custom_path_var }}'
```

Use

```
    content: 'export PATH=$PATH:{{ my_custom_path_var }}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to propose a clean solution for your task.

```
- name: "Add {{ new_path }} to PATH if not exists"
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: /etc/environment
    regexp: '^PATH="{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"'
    replace: 'PATH="{{ ansible_env.PATH }}:{{ new_path }}"'
  when: "new_path not in ansible_env.PATH"
```