# Echo bash variable in separate bash process

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a separate bash process and echo a variable which is set inside of it with no success. Nothing gets echoed.

```
bash -c "COMMIT_DIFF_FILE=diffs.diff && echo -e ${COMMIT_DIFF_FILE}"
```

What could be the problem here? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try `export $VARIABLE`?

Comment: as far as I understand, export can be used to inject a variable into the environment. Here, I'm creating a separate process which sets a new variable and then echos it.

Comment: `export` makes the variable available to sub-processes. BTW, I got there's a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export) with more info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to quote it right.

```
bash -c 'COMMIT_DIFF_FILE="diffs.diff" && echo "$COMMIT_DIFF_FILE"'
```

```
diffs.diff
```

You are quoting command to `bash -c` in double quotes which gets expanded in current shell where variable is not present.

If you want to use double quotes then escape `$`:

```
bash -c "COMMIT_DIFF_FILE=diffs.diff && echo \${COMMIT_DIFF_FILE}"
```