# How to get os env variable on OSX?

Tags: go, environment-variables

OSX Catalina & zsh as my terminal.

I have a command to start a psql connection :

```
db, err := pgx.Connect(context.Background(), os.Getenv("PSQL_URL"))
```

But the `os.Getenv("PSQL_URL")` is an empty string.

How to make sure go program can read my environment variable ?

In the terminal, if I `echo $PSQL_URL` I get the proper `postgresql://aod:toto@localhost/dbname`

If I export `PSQL_URL="postgresql://aod:toto@localhost/dbname"` before running main.go it works fine

I'm looking for a persistent way of doing it.

**UPDATE**

My mistake was as follow : 
Inside `~/.zhsrc` I did set 
`PSQL_URL="postgresql://aod:toto@localhost`

instead of

`export PSQL_URL="postgresql://aod:toto@localhost"`

Comment: *"If I export ... before running main.go it works fine"* That's the way to do it. Only exported variables become available in child processes. This has nothing to do with go, zsh or mac os. You can try it simply by running `echo $PSQL_URL` in a sub process. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export

Comment: But I have to export it everytime I run the program. Is there not a way to make it persistent ? I'm used to set my env variables in `/etc/environment` in linux and `os.Getenv` can read them just fine

Comment: I don't know how the terminal/shell inside VSCode works, sorry. Is it an actual shell and you do something like `go build; ./command` in it to run the app?

Comment: oh... I see. I used to `go build` all the time on linux. Whereas `go run main.go` uses shell variables. Thanks for the heads up !

Comment: `go run main.go` likely works just fine as well. The point I wanted to get was to whether the terminal sessions that VSCode creates are short-living (e.g. only exist for one build) or whether it's a single session across the lifetime of VSCode. There might be a VSCode specific solution.

Comment: hmm actually tested after a reboot and it does not matter if I use the regular terminal / vscode terminal (it is an actual shell) - nor if I use the binary created from `go build`. Kinda confused, still looking

Comment: Tried to echo $PSQL_URL in a sub process and it returns the proper variable.

Comment: Maybe we are talking about two different things here. I have an example app that just does `fmt.Println(os.Getenv("FOO"))`. I can do `export FOO="foo"` *once* and call the command multiple times after that (in the same shell) and see the value of the env variable every time. I.e `export FOO="foo"; ./test; ./test; ./test`. (note: normal terminal, not vscode) What are you doing?

Comment: Let's say I open a new terminal and then try to run `fmt.Println(os.Getenv("PSQL_URL"))` from `./main`. Printed variable will be an empty string. If I export `PSQL_URL="toto@url"` then run main it will work just fine. What I usually do on my linux computer is setting environment variables  in `/etc/environment` and I never have to export, hence my surprise reading your comment.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now. You want this env variable to exist "automatically" for every shell you are starting, is that correct? In that case, add `export PSQL_URL="..."` to your `~/.zshrc` file. This file is read whenver zsh is started.

Comment: thanks guys. My mistake was that in my `~/.zshrc` I had `PSQL_URL="..."` but not `export PSQL_URL="..."`, should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the correct way of reading an env variable in `go`.

The only thing that comes to my mind about what might be happening  is that you have two different terminal sessions. In one of them you set `PSQL_URL` (you are running the `echo` in this one) and in the other not (you are running your `go` app here).

EDIT

Expanded now with the your comments and Felix's, the problem here is that you export a variable, but don't make it permanent, so when you start a new session the variable doesn't exist. What you need to do is edit your `~/.zshrc` and add `export PSQL_URL=foo`, this way, whenever you start a new terminal session, the variable will be loaded.

Comment: All from the same terminal session (inside VSCode), using default zsh. I'm a bit lost as to how solve this