# Why exporting env var in bash script does not affect env?

Tags: bash

I want to set env variable in shell script. Shell script content is:

```
#!/bin/bash
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM"
```

I tried both `bash bin/enable_debug` and `bin/enable_debug`. After both command I get:

```
$ echo $XDEBUG_CONFIG

$
```

However if I run `export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM"` directly in cli it works. What's wrong with my method?

Comment: You need to [source](https://ss64.com/bash/source.html) your bash script for it to keep having an effect in the current shell

Comment: Here is a cross site duplicate if you want to durably set up environment variables : https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables

Comment: export makes the variables availaible in *child* processes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Defining a variable with or without export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try running your script as below:

```
. bin/enable_debug
```

OR

```
source bin/enable_debug
```

as indicated by @Aserre