# Is there a standard for a credentials file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, credentials

Is one of the following considered more standard than the others when storing credentials?

```
export DB_USER='aodhfoi2'

export DB_USER = aodhfoi2

export DB_USER="aodhfoi2"
```

Or, something else? Basically I'm looking to standardize various credentials and I haven't found a consistent example in what I've seen in various places on Google so was wondering if someone could recommend the best way to go about this.

Comment: What you are actually comparing is different forms of shell quoting.  There is no "standard" for which to use.  However, the 3 forms mean / do different things depending on the characters in the credential.  Read the shell manual or a tutorial about what form of quoting is *needed*.

Comment: The second one's invalid cause of the spaces. Maybe you meant `export DB_USER=aodhfoi2`?

Comment: It would be helpful if you indicated in your question what these credentials are for. The name `DB_USER` tends to imply some kind of database; you should say so explicitly. A lot of applications use credentials, and the practices for storing them can vary widely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining a variable with or without export](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1158091/608639).

Comment: @KeithThompson these would be loaded in a python application with various DB or Email or Server credentials.

Comment: @David542: As I said, that information should be in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a standard way. It is anyway considered a good practice to keep the passwords in reserved separate files from the main script. E.g.:

```
# .secretfile mode 600 (only root can read/write the file)
export pass=fweios
echo "Use $pass"
```

Then in the main script you can `source` the `.secretfile` and `unset` the variable when finished using it.

```
# mainscript
. .secretfile
# use $pass
unset pass
```