# Docker build-arg doesn't automatically pick up env variable when defined in separate line

Tags: bash, docker, environment-variables

Given this Dockerfile:

```
ARG PY_VERSION

FROM python:${PY_VERSION}-buster

CMD python -V
```

This `docker build . --build-arg PY_VERSION=3.8`
and this `PY_VERSION=3.8 docker build . --build-arg PY_VERSION` work.

But this

```sh
PY_VERSION=3.8
echo $PY_VERSION
3.8

docker build . --build-arg PY_VERSION

Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : ARG PY_VERSION
Step 2/3 : FROM python:${PY_VERSION}-buster
invalid reference format
```

Why doesn't docker pick up the env variable if it's not set in the same line?

versions:
`Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea`
`GNU bash, version 5.0.11(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0)`

Edit:
I'm aware that I can use `docker build . --build-arg PY_VERSION=$PY_VERSION`, just wondering why the example I provided does not work

Comment: @Inian this doesn't work, wouldn't that be equivalent to `docker build . --build-arg 3.8`?

Comment: Try `export PY_VERSION` before calling `docker`

Comment: @Mafor it works with export, why is that? does docker build run in a separate shell?

Comment: Without `export` the shell just sets a local variable; it's not actually an environment variable and isn't visible to commands the shell launches.

Comment: @RonSerruya see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1158231/9090751

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example provided, you are only declaring `PY_VERSION`, but you have not assigned it a value.

Per the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg),

> You may also use the --build-arg flag without a value, in which case the value from the local environment will be propagated into the Docker container being built

The built-in `env` command can be used to display available environment variables.

Per the [man page](https://ss64.com/bash/env.html),

> If no command name is specified following the environment specifications, the resulting environment is printed. This is like specifying a command name of 'printenv'.

Finally, to set an environment variable, one must use the built-in `export` command.

Per the [man page](https://ss64.com/bash/export.html),

> The supplied names are marked for automatic export to the environment of subsequently executed commands.

Comment: But docker should pick it automatically from the env variable, see the comments to the question, it works with `export`

Comment: Exactly, until you `export` the variable it has not been defined within the local context.