# Running EF Core migrations does not find environment variable in VS Code

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

Started building up an API solution with **Azure Functions** with runtime version **3.x** and **.NET Core 3.1**. In the solution using also **Entity Framework Core 3.1** with code first approach.

Check the *.csproj* file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
   <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
   <RootNamespace>project_name</RootNamespace>
   <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest> 
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.3" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.3">
     <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
     <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
   </PackageReference>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.3" />
</ItemGroup>
```

In the `StartUp` class I have the following to create the database context:

```
public RequestContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
{
   string sqlConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SqlConnectionString");
   var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<RequestContext>();
   optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(sqlConnectionString);
   return new RequestContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
}
```

So in the project I have my models for migrations and running the command with **.NET Core CLI** as the following:

```
dotnet-ef migrations add InitDb
```

Meanwhile running the **Azure Function** locally there are no issues, it can read the connection string value from **local.settings.json** file without any issues. Once running the migrations command I get the following error:

> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

**Question:**

So **it's clear** it cannot find the environment variable called `SqlConnectionString` once running the migrations command. Using **Visual Studio 2019** with **Package Manager Console** there is a way to solve this issue by setting up the environment variable as the following command before running migrations:

```
$env:SqlConnectionString="Server=<connection-string-value>"
```

It's pretty annoying to switch between **PMC** and **VS Code** just because of this step if I want to run migrations. I was checking different answers in similar topics but none of them helped me that much.

So is there any way to do the same and setup environment variable with **VS Code** terminal using bash? Or what could be the possible solution for this scenario?

Thank you!

Comment: please refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/26318/environment-variable-vs-shell-variable-whats-the-difference

Comment: @JimXu Thank you, that was helping me understanding what was leading to my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I originally tried to create an environment variable without the `export` keyword. So with the following command in bash `dotnet migrations` was leading the **Value cannot be null** error:

```
SqlConnectionString="Server=<connection-string-value>"
```

Based on [Jim Xu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10505040/jim-xu)'s comment I created an environment variable which seems to solve the issue as:

```
export SqlConnectionString="Server=<connection-string-value>"
```

See the full log:

```
$ export SqlConnectionString="Server=<connection-string-value>"

$ echo $SqlConnectionString
Server=<connection-string-value>

$ dotnet-ef migrations add InitDb
Build started...
Build succeeded.

Done. To undo this action, use 'ef migrations remove'
```

The references which were helping the solution were:

1. [Environment variable vs Shell variable, what's the difference?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26318/environment-variable-vs-shell-variable-whats-the-difference).
2. Also you can find further information in the SO link: [Defining a variable with or without export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export)

Thanks for sharing that link!