# Pass variables form one shell to another shell to execute a python script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have a python script that takes an argument and return a multiplication. I have this shell script pythoncall.sh:
`python /user/mult.py var1`

I want to run this for different argument values in a loop: second.sh

```
for i in 1 2 3
  do 
  var1=$i
  ./pythoncall.sh
done
```

but i don't get the result because i don't pass the variable i think. my error is IndexError: list index out of range.

the python script:

```
import sys
def main(argv):

    num1=sys.argv[1]
    len1=int(num1)*3
    print(len1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: what is the output of `print(sys.argv)`?

Comment: ['/user/mult.py','var'] var is the number i give

Comment: @sebis : Your program `pythoncall.sh` always invokes `mult.py` with the fixed string `var1` as argument. Inside your Python program, you try to convert this into an `int`, which of course fails.

Comment: @user1934428 see comments on my answer - this is not the cause of an `IndexError`

Comment: @sebis on what line do you get the `IndexError`?

Comment: @sebis : Well, the index error occurs because you try to fetch `argv[1]`, but pass only one argument  to Python.

Answer (score 0):

So, the direct answer is you need to [export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export) the variable for the second shell script to be able to see it:

```
export var1=$i
```

but why do you need the variable and second shell script at all? Why not just call the python script directly:

```
for i in 1 2 3
do
  python /user/mult.py $i
done
```

Comment: I tried with export and still i can not run it, ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'var1'.  I have to do it in this form.

Comment: Ah, you are passing the literal string `"var1"` to Python. Change the second shell script to `python /user/mult.py $var1` (with the `$` sign)

Comment: I add it and i have the problem : IndexError: list index out of range.