# Accessing Linux environment variables without assigned value

Tags: c++, c, shell, unix, environment-variables

I wrote small convenience functions for working with environment variables in C++ by wrapping `std::getenv`, `setenv` and `environ`. In addition to setting and getting the environment variables, I provided functionality to check if the current environment contains a certain variable.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>

template <typename VAR_TYPE>
void set(const std::string& variableName, VAR_TYPE varValue, bool overwrite = false) {
    if (!setenv(variableName.c_str(), std::string(variableValue).c_str(), overwrite)) {
      if (errno == ENOMEM) {
        throw std::bad_alloc();
      } else if (errno == EINVAL) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Variable name invalid: "  + variableName);
      } else {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to set environment variable " + variableName);
      }
    }
  }

std::string load(const std::string& variableName, const std::string& defaultValue = "") {
    if (const char* envVariable = std::getenv(variableName)) {
      return std::string(envVariable);
    }
    return defaultValue;
  }

bool contains(const std::string& variableName) {
    for (char** currentEnviron = environ; *currentEnviron; currentEnviron++) {
      if (!std::strncmp(variableName.c_str(), *currentEnviron, variableName.length())) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

However, [by definition](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html), this only allows to access environment variables that are in the form `NAME=VALUE`.

In `bash`, I can do the following:

```
$> export SOME_VAR
$> export -p | grep SOME_VAR
declare -x SOME_VAR
```

Apparently, `SOME_VAR` is defined somewhere, even if I dont assign a value to it. When I run `printenv` however, which uses the same methods I use in my wrapper, `SOME_VAR` is not listed. I have had a look at `/proc/self/environ` but this only lists variables with assigned value.

My questions are:

1. What is the difference between an environment variable defined as `SOME_VAR_WITH_VALUE=42` and `SOME_VAR_WITHOUT_VALUE`.
2. Is there a possibility in C/C++ to access environment variables without values?

Comment: Your check, `-z $SOME_VAR`, doesn't check if `SOME_VAR` is set, but if length of `$SOME_VAR` is 0. If `SOME_VAR` is not set or if it is set to empty string this will return true.

Comment: Oh my, you are right. I edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shell has a notion of [internal and exported environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export).

A shell command like `ABC=xyz` sets an internal variable (which can be seen in Bash using `set`).

To export an internal variable, there's the `export` command.

`export ABC=xyz` will create an internal variable **and** export it (exported ones can be seen using `env`).

`export ABC` by itself does not define any variable, it simple tags `ABC` to be exported, **when** it's defined.

Try this for example:

```
$ ABC=xyz
$ set | grep ABC
ABC=xyz
$ env | grep ABC
```

And now with `export`:

```
$ export ABC
$ set | grep ABC
$ env | grep ABC
$ ABC=xyz
$ set | grep ABC
ABC=xyz
$ env | grep ABC
ABC=xyz
```

Notice how the variable got exported the moment it was set. So `export ABC` is purely a shell feature, it does not modify the environment. There is no API for it.

To set an environment variable with an empty value, use `export ABC=""`:

```
$ export ABC=""
$ env | grep ABC
ABC=
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! So the closest I can get to having "empty" variables (without jumping through hoops by for example parsing the output of `declare`) is by using `export ABC=""`

Answer (score 0):

First try this:

```bash
export SOME_VAR
set | grep SOME_VAR
```

The second line will return nothing. That is because the first line doesn't define `SOME_VAR`.

As for your two questions:

1. `export VARIABLE` has no effect. It does not create variable with no value, nor does it change value of an already set variable.
2. Environment variable always has a value, but that value may be empty string. If you try to access nonexistent variable you will get `NULL`.

Comment: When I use `export SOME_VAR` and then run `export -p`, `SOME_VAR` is listed as `declare -x SOME_VAR`. So it seems that the `export` statement seems to have some effect

Comment: True, the name is exported, you are correct -- `export VAR` has effect. But it does not define `VAR`'s value. So `VAR` will be exported, but it's value will still not be defined.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, `bash` is just another Linux program. There's limited magic involved. It can alter the `libc` `environ` variables, but it can also have its own internal variables. If you don't see `SOME_VAR_WITHOUT_VALUE` in `/proc/sef/environ`, you can deduce that it's some kind of bash-internal variable.

Note that `bash`, like most Linux programs, can be run multiple times in parallel. Environments are separate between processes. So even in C you can't access any of the bash environment variables *directly*. You're taking advantage of the fact that bash copies its environment to your environment, when your process is started. But `env -i your_process` will stop even that.