# Perl $ENV not accessing environment variable

Tags: bash, perl, environment-variables

Here is a WSL bash session in which I attempt to access an Environment variable within a perl one liner:

```
$ ln='Hello World'
$ echo $ln
Hello World
$ perl -E 'say $ENV{q(ln)}'

$
```

Why does the perl expression `$ENV{q(ln)}` not contain the expected Environment variable `ln` ?

Comment: @Wes : Because it is just a shell variable, but not an environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `export` the environment variable.

```
$ ln='Hello World'
$ export ln
```

or

```
$ export ln='Hello World'
```

See section 3.2.3 in the [Bash Beginners' Guide](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html), and the top answer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export)