# Sourced file is not included in printenv/env

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

In a bash shell I try to source a file and then have the variables included in the output of `printenv`/`env` but they are not. I couldn't find anything about this behavior so far on the web.

MWE:

```
echo "HALLO=bla" > envfile.env
source envfile.env
echo $HALLO # returns "bla"
printenv | grep HALLO # returns nothing
```

Is it due to `export` how do I make sure the variables from a file are included in `printenv`?

**Edit:** To clarify the actual problem, I want to set a variable so that it is shown in printenv, (which is used by `popper` to set the environment in the docker containers).

Comment: Have you tried `echo "export HALLO=BLA"`?

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: See: [Defining a variable with or without export](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1158091/3776858)

Comment: @white_gecko: `printenv` outputs only environment variables, but `HALO` is just a variable, not an environment variable.