# Can't wrap curl within tsocks?

Tags: proxy, tsocks

I build a socks5 proxy.

```
url="https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/-/wikis/MailConcept"
curl --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:1080   $url
```

curl command can get the url via socks5 proxy.
To install tsocks:

```
sudo apt install tsocks
```

And set the configuration:

```
vim /etc/socks/tsocks.conf
server = 127.0.0.1
server_type = 5
server_port = 1080
```

Let curl run in tsocks:

```
tsocks curl $url
```

It can't get nothing!
It is no use to set variable with export:

```
export url="https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/-/wikis/MailConcept"
tsocks curl $url
curl: (7) Failed to connect to gitlab.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

Answer (score -1):

Curl becomes a subprocess of tsocks and with the way you declare the variable, it can not be accessed from a subprocess:

`url="https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/-/wikis/MailConcept"`

change this to

`export url="https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/-/wikis/MailConcept"`

See also:
[Defining a variable with or without export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export)