# Exporting a function local variable to the environment

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Consider the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

t_export() {
  declare dummy="Hello"
  export dummy
  echo dummy: $dummy
  echo printenv dummy: $(printenv dummy)
}

t_export
echo dummy: $dummy
echo printenv dummy: $(printenv dummy)
```

Output:

```
dummy: Hello
printenv dummy: Hello
dummy:
printenv dummy:
```

How do you explain this? I thought the environment is always global and therefore the variable `dummy` would also be visible outside the function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`export` doesn't copy values in to the current environment. Instead, it sets the export attribute on a *name*. When a new processes is started, any variables marked with that attribute are copied (along with their current values) into the environment of the new process.

When `t_export` returns, the variable `dummy` goes out of scope, which means it is no longer available to be exported to new processes.

Answer (score 6):

`declare` inside a functions defaults to `local`. Use `-g` to declare a global from inside a function.

Comment: I understood that it is local. But after export it should be in the environment, no? Apparently it is removed from the environment once you leave the function?

Comment: `export` has nothing to do with global variables. It marks a *name* to be copied into the environment of a new child process. It doesn't immediately copy the variable into the *current* environment.

Comment: @chepner apparently it does, see the `printenv` inside the function.

Comment: Yes, when `printenv` (or more precisely, the process to execute the subshell that starts `printenv`), the values of any current variables marked as exported are copied into the new process. They don't actually exist in the environment of the current process. (It's a subtle distinction, and one that is hard to confirm directly because the shell doesn't provide a way to examine its own environment, but you are seeing the evidence by `dummy` no longer existing when you run `printenv` *after* `t_export` returns.)

Comment: If you have a `proc` filesystem, you can see that an exported variable does not appear in `/proc/$$/environ`.