# Do you need to include export for environment variables in bash profile / zshrc?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

Do you need to include export for *environment variables* in Bash profile / zshrc?

I'm using Z shell (Zsh) for my terminal and in my `.zshrc` file I have the two lines:

```
varOne="foo"

export varTwo="bar"
```

When I echo either variable (ex: `echo $varOne`) within the terminal, the correct value is output.

So is there a difference when prefixing the environment variable declaration with `export` inside the `.zshrc` file?

Comment: If you do not `export` variable, it's only available inside the `.zshrc` file. Also maybe see related Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1158093/4676641

Comment: the first one is just for assigning a variable and the second one (with export), sends the variable to child shell proceses created from that shell. https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-variables-export

Comment: @tentative No, it's available in the shell that sources `.zshrc`. The shell doesn't have file-local variables, because the shell has no concept of modules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So is there a difference when prefixing the environment variable declaration with export inside the .zshrc file?

Yes, one is an environment variable and the other isn't.

The difference doesn't matter (much) to *your* shell, but to processes started *by* your shell. Environment variables are inherited by child processes, regular shell variables are not.

```
~ % foo=3; printenv foo
~ % export foo=3; printenv foo
3
```

In the first case, `printenv` has no variable named `foo` in *its* environment; in the second case, it does.