# bash: defining variables in .bashrc to use in any external SH script

Tags: bash

In my bashrc there is a function which defines some variables

```
quick_amber(){
home=$(pwd)
project="MDtest"

ref_folder="${home}"

# run script from USB stick which will use all of these variable
chmod +x /media/user/KINGSTON/extra/test.sh
/media/user/KINGSTON/extra/test.sh
}
```

these variables should be used inside of the test.sh script in the following manner :

```
# find pdb filles in any current directory and print its names
#!/bin/bash
for ref_pdb in ${ref_folder}/*.pdb; do
  ref_title2=$(basename "$ref_pdb")
  ref_title3="${ref_title2/.pdb}"
echo "let's test it"
echo $project: $ref_title3 found in "$ref_folder"
done
```

The problem that it prints only one line with all filles, and does not see any variables defined in the bashrc function, something like:

```
let's test it

: MD_BAK_0deg.pdb MD_BAK_300deg.pdb MD_BAK_360deg.pdb MD_BAK_60deg.pdb found in
```

I've tried to define all variables in bashrc like global or local but it did not change anything. What should be corrected ?

Comment: Did you run the script in a fresh shell that sourced the .bashrc? Note that some terminals don't source it in new windows/tabs.

Comment: normally I had sourced it beforhand so all functions defined in the bashrc recognized correctly. Othervise if I define all variables in the test.sh they are recognized OK so the problem in the communication between the both

Comment: You need to export a variable for it to be seen by child processes. Even then, this is considered extremely bad practice: `.bashrc` has settings for _interactive_ users; it isn't read by noninteractive scripts, and many processes aren't the child of an interactive shell in the first place.

Comment: More pointedly, users are expected to be able to change their interactive configuration _without unexpectedly breaking their scripts_. Similarly, people generally expect to be able to copy a script from host-A to host-B without needing to copy their personal shell configuration too, or to share those scripts with a coworker who keeps their shell configured completely differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to `export` the variables that are to be referenced in a follow-on shell script invocation, eg:

```
quick_amber(){

export home=$(pwd)
export project="MDtest"
export ref_folder="${home}"

# run script from USB stick which will use all of these variable
chmod +x /media/user/KINGSTON/extra/test.sh
/media/user/KINGSTON/extra/test.sh
}
```

Comment: Right, I gotcha ! So we need to use obligatory EXPORT var in order that the var will be recognized in the sh scripts executed from the same function. Does this VAR remain global ? Will it be recognized by several sh scripts executed from the same or other functions placed in .bashrc ??

Comment: if your operations are being performed within the same (login) session then, yes, it should be available to follow-on functions and scripts; easiest way to verify this ... *`when in doubt try it out`* :-)  **NOTE:** keep in mind this applies for variables that are exported from within a *function* ... variables exported from within a (shell) *script* will only be available within the scope of that script (or any subscripts called by said script)

Comment: Right, thank you very much ! so in bash we do have three kind of variables: global (w/o any specifications), local (works within the given function) and enviromental (export), right ?? when do I need the export var in other cases ??

Comment: generally speaking `export`ing a var makes it available to subprocesses called by the current process; there are nuances when it comes to 'subprocess' vs 'subshell' (not the same thing); a web search on `when to export variable in bash` will provide more for you reading pleasure, eg, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21722203), [this](https://superuser.com/q/153371) and [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/bash-export-variable)